# How can I install Python modules programmatically / through a Python script without using pip, for platforms that lack it?

Tags: python, pip, distutils, easy-install, maya

Can I download and install Python modules from PyPi strictly inside a script, without using a shell **at all**?

I use a non-standard Python environment, Autodesk Maya 2012's Python interpreter. This does not come with `easy_install` or `pip`, and there is no shell, only a `python` script interpreter invoked by the main Maya executable. Copying and pasting `ez_setup.py`'s contents into the script editor window and running it correctly installs an `easy_install` somewhere into Maya's directory, but the script incorrectly records the Python interpreter as `...maya.exe` instead of `...mayapy.exe` Furthermore, using `easy_install` requires a shell.

The objective is to deliver a Python script that, e.g., installs NumPy into the Maya Python system. This could be accomplished by dropping eggs into the `site-packages` directory, but that requires manual user intervention. Anything an end user has to do outside the Maya environment is essentially untouchable, especially messing with the file system. But messing with the filesystem through a script? That's fine.

Is there something more elegant than ez_setup.py + editing the resulting easy_install...py's + subprocess calls? I feel like this is a basic feature. I see documentation online for programmatic module installation through `pip`, but `pip` needs to be installed first!

What is the most elegant way to install a module strictly within the confines of a script?

Comment: Does assigning `sys.executable` to the path to `mayapy.exe` before running `ez_setup.py` work?

Comment: Thanks: this fixes `ez_setup`, but it requires knowing where `mayapy.exe` is. More path hacking...

Comment: If you don't need easy_install's dependency resolution, simply `exec()`-ing the `setup.py` file might work

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Installing easy_install for Maya on windows.

1. Download [ez_setup.py](http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py).
2. open windows cmd elevated (start, type *cmd*, *rmb* click on it ->run as administrator)
3. change the cmd directory to x:\maya install dir\bin

   - example: cd c:\Program Files\MayaXX\bin
4. execute following command mayapy x:\WhereYouSaved\ez_setup.py

Now easy install should be set up properly. You may want to still do following steps:

5. cd  x:\maya install dir\python\scripts
6. rename all files in this folder to start with ma

   - example: for %i in (*) do ren %i ma%i
7. add this folder to your path

   - hit win+e
   - *rmb* my computer and choose properties
   - Advanced system settings -> Environment variables
   - search variable path edit it and append ;x:\maya install dir\python\scripts

Now you can call **maeasy_install pythonModule** from cmd for installing stuff. Also you can call following inside Maya to install modules:

```
from setuptools.command import easy_install
easy_install.main( ["pythonModule"] )
```

**NOTE:** If Maya is installed in program files then you can not really install stuff without elevating. Unless you change disk permissions to the Maya python directory.

Comment: Thanks. `easy_install.main()` is exactly what I'm looking for, because executing a modified `ez_setup.py` inside Maya gets it installed too.

Answer (score 11):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from __future__ import print_function

REQUIREMENTS = [ 'distribute', 'version', 'Cython', 'sortedcollection' ]
try:
    from setuptools import find_packages
    from distutils.core import setup
    from Cython.Distutils import build_ext as cython_build
    import sortedcollection
except:
    import os, pip
    pip_args = [ '-vvv' ]
    proxy = os.environ['http_proxy']
    if proxy:
        pip_args.append('--proxy')
        pip_args.append(proxy)
    pip_args.append('install')
    for req in REQUIREMENTS:
        pip_args.append( req )
    print('Installing requirements: ' + str(REQUIREMENTS))
    pip.main(initial_args = pip_args)

    # do it again
    from setuptools import find_packages
    from distutils.core import setup
    from Cython.Distutils import build_ext as cython_build
    import sortedcollection
```

Comment: This looks really interesting. Does this try importing `sortedcollection`, and if it fails to import, install the package?

Comment: @DoctorPangloss: Yes, correct. It tries to import Cython and sortedcollection inside the try/catch block. When it fails, it uses pip to install dependencies listed in ``REQUIREMENTS``. Then it tries to import cython and sortedcollections again, which should work this time.

Answer (score 1):

To make it work, open the `ez_setup.py` file and simply add an `s` after `http` at this line:

```
DEFAULT_URL     = "http://pypi.python.org/packages/%s/s/setuptools/" % sys.version[:3]
```

so that it becomes

```
DEFAULT_URL     = "https://pypi.python.org/packages/%s/s/setuptools/" % sys.version[:3]
```