# Tumblr xAuth without oauth2 lib

Tags: python, oauth, oauth-2.0, tumblr, maya

I'm working on a plugin for Autodesk Maya. The application's Python libraries aren't in the same location as the normal python libraries (Maya uses Python 2.6.4). Basically, the 3D artists are neither willing nor able to install oath2 to the correct location on their machines. Its equally likely that I'm ignorant of a way to do this for them.

Ultimately, I would like to be able to allow the 3D artists to download a simple python file, run it, sign in and click a button that uploads an update of what they're working on. I've already gotten an email version working - smpt doesn't have nearly as many hoops to jump through (not that that's necessarily a good thing).

Is there any way to deliver the functionality of the oauth2 module without having to do some complicated install? Do you know of any ways to bundle the oauth2 module without having to go through an installation process? My google-fu has failed me on these points thus far.

Answer (score 0):

Modify [ez_setup.py](http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py) (also see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966147/how-can-i-install-python-modules-programmatically-through-a-python-script/13016849#13016849)), include everything up to the long line gap.

Then put:

```
use_setuptools()

from setuptools.command import easy_install
easy_install.main( ["oauth2"] )
from pkg_resources import require
require('oauth2')
```

Add whatever you need after this. Possible problems:

- user needs possibly to be admin (this could be circumvented but if the artist does not have admin then its not really their business to install stuff  anyway)
- clicking not possible user has to actually run the script inside maya with 
  **script editor -> load script**
- installer may be easier
- I did not actually have time to test this porperly

**PS:** Not all mayas run python 2.6.4