# Python extensions and maya 2012

Tags: python, installation, maya

When I follow this [link](http://chayanvinayak.blogspot.kr/2012/05/how-to-install-win32-extension-for.html) to install numpy my Autodesk maya 2012. I know maya 2012 has own python interpreter version 2.6.4 so that I installed numpy 1.7.1, Python 2.6 version.

```
import sys

sys.path.append("C:/Python26/Lib/site-package/numpy")
sys.path.append("C:/Python26/Lib/site-package/numpy/lib")
import numpy
# Error: ImportError: No module named numpy # 
sys.path.append("C:/Python26/Lib/site-package")
import numpy
# Error: ImportError: No module named numpy #
```

After I follow this instruction, and execute commands at the python interpreter, It causes an error. However, It has already applied on the python 2.6 standalone. How to apply extensions on the maya interpreter?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might find this link helpful: http://animateshmanimate.com/2011/03/30/python-numpy-and-maya-osx-and-windows/

It might also be possible to do it via easy_install although (like so much of maya python) there are some catches, as detailed in this question: [How can I install Python modules programmatically / through a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966147/how-can-i-install-python-modules-programmatically-through-a-python-script)