# Emulate pip install -r requirements from shell

Tags: python, pip

Is it possible to achieve the same behaviour of:

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

But programmatically with python?

For example (**pseudocode**):

```
from pip.reqs import install_requirements

install_requirements(file='requirements.txt')
```

And if not why? What is the best practice?

Comment: Here's a similar question: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966147/how-can-i-install-python-modules-programmatically-through-a-python-script][1] Hope it helps you. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966147/how-can-i-install-python-modules-programmatically-through-a-python-script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need pip to be install prior to

```
import pip

# to install requirements
pip.main(['install', '-r', 'requirements.txt'])

# to install one package
pip.main(['install', 'package_name'])
```