# Deploying Python modules for 3D software

Tags: python, pyqt, pyside, maya

I have been developing a fairly extensive library of python modules that automate the more time consuming parts of "3D character development" for games/film/tv.

All of my code up until a few months ago has been run within [Maya's](http://www.autodesk.com/products/maya/overview) dedicated python interpreter, however, my GUIs are built in PySide/PyQt, and so, run just fine in mac/windows/linux or a few other Graphics programs such as [Nuke](http://www.thefoundry.co.uk/products/nuke-product-family/nuke/), [XSI](http://www.autodesk.com/products/softimage/overview), [Max](http://www.autodesk.com/products/3ds-max/overview).

What I would really like to figure out is a "simple" way to distribute my code to various different people ---> using various different operating Systems ---> potentially using various applications ([Nuke](http://www.thefoundry.co.uk/products/nuke-product-family/nuke/), [XSI](http://www.autodesk.com/products/softimage/overview), [Max](http://www.autodesk.com/products/3ds-max/overview)), which, in turn, have their own dedicated python interpreters.

The obvious option would be pip and easy_install.. These modules are clearly the "right" way to go, but its not really clear how a user would install/run them under the dedicated python installs that ship with Maya/Nuke/ etc...Though, it does seem possible [(as explained here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966147/how-can-i-install-python-modules-programmatically-through-a-python-script). Still Its going to be a pretty big barrier for a less-technical user.

Any help or points in the right direction would be immensely appreciated..

Answer (score 3):

I would not say that pip/easy_install are the 'right' way for this problem. They are pretty good (not quite 'great') tools for motivated, technically inclined users -- but even in that context they have issues (such as unintended upgrades or deletions).  Most importantly, they are opt-in methods: nobody can make you pip unless you want to. This means users can accidentally or deliberately get themselves into very different positions from each other, which makes support and maintenance a nightmare.

I've had very good luck in Maya distributing a zipped file containing a complete environment - all the modules etc. `userSetup.py` adds that zip to the path and the Python's native zipimport functionality handles the rest.  This makes sure that there is only one file to maintain and distribute. It also fixes the common problem of leftover .pyc files creating havok after .py files get moved or renamed. Since this is all standard python, I'd assume this will work for any app-specific python that uses a 2.6+ version of python, though I've never tried it in Nuke or Max.

The main wrinkle will be modules with .pyd or other binary components, typically these don't work inside the zip files. I include a bootstrap routine which unpacks those to a (disposable) location on the user's disk and adds that to the path.

There's a detailed discussion of the method [here](http://techartsurvival.blogspot.com/2014/07/save-environment-2-i-am-egg-man.html) and some background [here](http://techartsurvival.blogspot.com/2014/06/save-environment.html)