# Install a Python module from within a Python script

Tags: python-3.x

Technically this is a duplicate of [How can I install Python modules programmatically / through a Python script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12966147/how-can-i-install-python-modules-programmatically-through-a-python-script), but the answer to that question is a little too specific and outdated anyway.

I'd like my Python program to be able to download and install its dependencies with pip without user input (further than a "do you want to install this" anyhow). What's the recommended way to go about this?

Comment: Doesn't the second answer to that question work for you?

Comment: @0xc0de Didn't see that one. Still, it's not very nice code and I'd like a more... uhh, maybe canonical solution.

Comment: I personally doubt that the requirement 'without user input' will have or be encouraged to have a 'canonical' solution. I personally don't like scripts installing things (even if they are modules), and would really like the confirmation prompts.

Comment: @0xc0de I did say there'd be confirmation messages.