# Pip install directly from Python with proxy

Tags: python, proxy, pip, pypi

I'm trying to use pip inside python script.
I encountered a problem with proxy.

When I'm installing module from cmd I'm using this command:

```
python -m pip install [module] --proxy=[proxy]
```

Inside python script I'm using the following code:

```
def install(package):
    pip.main(['install', '--proxy==[proxy]', package])
```

but it ends with error:

```
[33m  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None)) 
after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', 
NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages.urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection 
object at 0x043717F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',))': 
/simple/pandas/[0m
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12937533/use-pip-install-uninstall-inside-a-python-script

Comment: Is it working when you use just one '=' in your `--proxy==[proxy]` statement?

Comment: @ChristianEichelmann it works! Thank you.