# upgrading python module within code

Tags: python, pip

My question relates to this question: [Installing python module within code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/installing-python-module-within-code), but involves upgrading the module.

I've tried

```
packages=['apscheduler','beautifulsoup4','gdata']

def upgrade(packages):
    for package in packages:
        pip.main(['install --upgrade', package])
```

and

```
def upgrade(packages):
    for package in packages:
        pip.main(['install', package + ' --upgrade'])
```

Comment: Did you try `pip.main(['install', '--upgrade', package])`?

Comment: no i didn't. I know I should be flogged. what do i do with the question now? delete it?

Comment: I added it as answer, if it works you can accept it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try `pip.main(['install', '--upgrade', package])`.

"--upgrade" is a separate command-line argument, so you need to pass it separately to `main`.

Comment: `from pip._internal import main` as main is moved to internal. see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50764560/6306190

Answer (score 2):

[BrenBarn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25862484/2128530) matches the style of OP's code, but [Richard Wheatley's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39171821/2128530) is closer to my code.

Richard's answer has a couple of issues I'd like to fix, though, and I didn't want to edit his because the differences are reasonably significant.

```
from subprocess import call

my_packages = ['apscheduler', 'beautifulsoup4', 'gdata']

def upgrade(package_list):
    call(['pip', 'install', '--upgrade'] + package_list)
```

Notes:

- No need to import the `pip` module (`subprocess` calls the `pip` binary found in its path)
- Unecessary use of `shell=True` in `call()` (and other `subprocess` functions) should be be avoided, as [it puts responsibility on the programmer to protect against shell injection vulnerabilities](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/subprocess.html#security-considerations).  (Not really an issue here, but good as a general rule.)
- A single invocation of `pip install` accepts an arbitrary number of package names, and a single use of `--upgrade` will apply to all of them.
- We can leverage the previous fact and Python's list concatenation to avoid writing a loop.

Answer (score 0):

I now this is an old thread but I have come across it many times and I think I should give another solution since I've used this one. To me this is more user-friendly.

```
import pip
from subprocess import call

packages=['apscheduler','beautifulsoup4','gdata']

def upgrade(packages):
    for package in packages:
        call("pip install --upgrade " + package, shell=True)
```

After reading the following [Actual meaning of 'shell=True' in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess) post, it appears that the shell=True command was not needed and is probably not the best idea.
    `import pip` is not needed since I do not call `pip.main` as was seen in some previous answers.

So the new code could be:
    from subprocess import call

```
packages=['apscheduler','beautifulsoup4','gdata']

def upgrade(packages):
    for package in packages:
        call("pip install --upgrade " + package)
```

As for the other answers, I prefer passing the specific string and loop.
You will not get a performance hit or gain using either method.