# Upgrade package from script using pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-3.5

Using pip from a (python 3.5) script, how can i upgrade a package i previously installed via the command line (using `pip install`)?

Something like

```
import pip
pip.install("mysuperawesomepackage", upgrade=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this:

```
pip.main(['install', '--upgrade', package]).
```

Ref - [upgrading python module within code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25862416/upgrading-python-module-within-code)

Answer (score 1):

```
import pip

def install(package):
    pip.main(['install', package])

# Example
if __name__ == '__main__':
    install('mysuperawesomepackage')
```