# AttributeError: Module Pip has no attribute 'main'

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to build the python api for an open source project called Zulip and I keep running into the same issue as indicated by the screenshot below.

I am running python3 and my pip version is 10.0.0. The file in question is `setup.py` and the code that is messing up is when the `pip.main()` attribute is accessed to install a package.

Now, I know this build should succeed because its an open source project, but I have been trying for hours to fix the dependency issue regarding `pip.main()`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Seems similar problem mentioned here: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000168364-Pycharm-Virenv-AttributeError-module-pip-has-no-attribute-main-occured-

Comment: Screenshots are not helpful to other users as the error is not searchable. Please post your error in the body of the question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python pip3 - cannot import name 'main'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49836676/python-pip3-cannot-import-name-main)

Answer (score 76):

```
python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade pip==9.0.3
```

[pip issue: rollback](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5240)

Comment: If there's an issue with Pip wouldn't it be good to not constantly try to push the user to upgrade PIP to a broken version?: You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 10.0.1 is available.

Comment: also, `python3` is now just `python`

Comment: Now latest version is `19.2.3` so `python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade pip==19.2.3` is working for me

Comment: @Gulzar it's wise to explicitly use the python version in case multiple versions are installed. for some the alias for python would point to python2..

Answer (score 34):

It appears that pip did a refactor and moved main to internal. There is a comprehensive discussion about it here: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5240

A workaround for me was to change

```
import pip
pip.main(...)
```

to

```
from pip._internal import main
main(...)
```

I recommend reading through the discussion, I'm not sure this is the best approach, but it worked for my purposes.

Answer (score 28):

First run

```py
import pip
pip.__version__
```

If the result is '10.0.0', then it means that you installed pip successfully 
since pip 10.0.0 doesn't support pip.main() any more, you may find this helpful 
https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program

Use something like

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.check_call(["python", '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'pkg']) # install pkg
subprocess.check_call(["python", '-m', 'pip', 'install',"--upgrade", 'pkg']) # upgrade pkg
```

---

pip 10.0.1 still doesn't support main 
You can choose to DOWNGRADE your pip version via following command:

```
python -m pip install --upgrade pip==9.0.3
```

Comment: This in itself didn't work on my MacOS. Instead all pip* folders out of my `/site-packages/` directory and then re-installed Python3.6.

Comment: I missed the critical word "move" from my comment: Move all pip* folders out of '/site-packages/'...

Answer (score 7):

This helps me, https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

If you are using python3 and not set it default. do this,

```
python3 get-pip.py
```

It works for me.

Comment: This one works for me. my pip3 Successfully upgraded to the latest pip-18.0. And the command pip3 works without errors in my terminal.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me.   Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

My solution is to check the version number of pip and use the import the correct main function correctly

```
import pip

if int(pip.__version__.split('.')[0])>9:
    from pip._internal import main
else:
    from pip import main
def install(package):
    main(['install', package])
```

Answer (score 6):

To verify whether is your `pip` installation problem, try using `easy_install` to install an earlier version of pip:

```
easy_install pip==9.0.1
```

If this succeed, `pip` should be working now. Then you can go ahead to install any other version of `pip` you want with:

```
pip install pip==10....
```

Or you can just stay with `version 9.0.1`, as your project requires version >= 9.0.

Try building your project again.

Answer (score 3):

If `python -m pip install --upgrade pip==9.0.3` doesn't work, and you're using Windows,

1. Navigate to this directory and move the pip folders elsewhere.

[image]

2. Close your IDE if you have it open.
3. Press **'Repair'** on Python 3.

[image]

4. Your IDE should cease to detect pip packages and prompt you to install them. Install and keep the last stable pip version by blocking automatic updates.
   [image]

Answer (score 2):

Pip 10.0.* doesn't support main.

You have to downgrade to pip 9.0.3.

Answer (score 1):

Try this command.

```
python -m pip install --user pip==9.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

It works well:

```
 py -m pip install --user --upgrade pip==9.0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit file:
C:\Users\kpate\hw6\python-zulip-api\zulip_bots\setup.py in line 108

to

```
rcode = pip.main(['install', '-r', req_path, '--quiet'])
```

do

```
rcode = getattr(pip, '_main', pip.main)(['install', '-r', req_path, '--quiet'])´
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Windows. But for mac users, use this:

```
pip install --upgrade pip==9.0.3
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this problem upgrading to latest version

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```

My version:
*pip 18.1 from /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)*

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error while using pip on anaconda3 4.4.0 (python 3.6) on windows.

I fixed the problem by the following command:

```
easy_install pip==18.*  ### installing the latest version pip
```

Or if lower version pip required, mention the same in the command.

Or you can try installing the lower version and then upgrading the same to latest version as follow:

```
easy_install pip==9.0.1

easy_install --upgrade pip
```

Answer (score 0):

For me this issue occured when I was running python while within my site-packages folder. If I ran it anywhere else, it was no longer an issue.