# Why do I get ModuleNotFoundError while importing docx?

Tags: python, ms-word, python-docx

I'm trying to import Document from docx but with this ModuleNotFoundError occures.

```
from docx import Document

# just for testing:
doc = Document()
```

When running this I am getting folowing output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/finnm/PycharmProjects/MesseMahlzeiten/TestScipt.py", line 1, in <module>
    from docx import Document
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'docx'
```

Since it may could be helpful I show you what pip-installation outputs:

```
C:\Users\finnm>pip install python-docx
Collecting python-docx
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e4/83/c66a1934ed5ed8ab1dbb9931f1779079f8bca0f6bbc5793c06c4b5e7d671/python-docx-0.8.10.tar.gz
Requirement already satisfied: lxml>=2.3.2 in c:\users\finnm\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages (from python-docx) (4.4.1)
Installing collected packages: python-docx
  Running setup.py install for python-docx ... done
Successfully installed python-docx-0.8.10
```

Comment: Are you sure you're running the same Python version as `pip`?

Comment: I already thought about that. I'm pretty sure I have just one installed but is there a way to ensure this?

Comment: Maybe you have two Pythons. Check versions `pip -V` and `python -V`. You can also install using `python -m pip install ...` to make sure it install in correct Python.

Comment: Also worth double-checking which python interpreter you're using for your pycharm: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-local-python-interpreters.html

Comment: Tried all your suggestion.... pip is installed for python version 3.6, python displays 3.6.4 (should be the same, shouldn't it?). PyCharm is also using python 3.6. Nothing confusing to me at this.

Comment: try running - import pip...pip.main(['install','python-docx']) from within the python shell to make sure you're using the proper pip for python version/interpreter you're using

Comment: Doing this I'm getting: AttributeError: module 'pip' has no attribute 'main' ...

Comment: there's some discussion on this issue here- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49839610/attributeerror-module-pip-has-no-attribute-main

I think you'll be able to get the command to work if you check here..some versions have main in different places

Comment: Actually, looks like you have already figured that out :)

Answer (score 1):

**Solved**

I was able to pip install python-docx by doing pip-installation actually inside my script.

This question  answers to it:
[Installing python module within code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/installing-python-module-within-code)

---

Thanks to everyone for helping me.