# The "pip.main" function no longer exists

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip, arduino-uno

I was coding a code for my Arduino UNO, and I followed a tutorial because this was the first time I had used python on a Arduino UNO. The guy in the tutorial used `pip.main`. I was just trying to get to a start on the code. I am using Python  3.7.5 and pip version 19.2.3. I have already tried looking around in Stack Overflow and other similar websites, but everything the community suggested didn't work. I also have very limited time to fix this problem. Here is my code:

```
try:
  from pyfirmata import Arduino, util
except:
  #the problem is here
  from pip._internal import main
  main(['install', 'pyfirmara'])
  from pyfirmata import Arduino, util

board = Arduino('')

iterator = util.Iterator(board)
iterator.start()

#code here

board.exit()
```

**Help would be greatly appreciated!!**

Comment: The interface of `pip` has changed. In general name starting with an underscore are considered private and might change without notice. You should not rely on them.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AttributeError: Module Pip has no attribute 'main'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49839610/attributeerror-module-pip-has-no-attribute-main)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+main

Answer (score 0):

The module `pip._module` is meant to be private and should not be used, as indicated by the [leading underscore which is a Python convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

The *pip* tool in general is not meant to be used as a library. See the [pip documentation on "Using pip from your program"](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program) for details and alternative solutions.