# Unable to install pip package on Python3.4.0 windows 7 64 bit

Tags: python, pip, python-3.4, python-packaging

I am using the command `python -m pip install` on the python34 folder but its giving me the following error:

```
Error while finding specs for 'pip._main_'{<class attribute error'>: 'module' object has no attribute'wraps'): 'pip' is a package and cannot be directly executed.
```

I have seen similar questions posted and I have also tried command prompt from scripts folder inside python34 folder and used the command "pip install" which seemed to work for others but I am still seeing the same error.

Comment: fwiw, python3.4 is end of lifed, it's possible you're using a too-new version of pip for python3.4 and getting an error because of that?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I originally had pip 7.1, with pip update it would go to the latest version of pip that's 20.0 which isn't supported by Python 3.4. This further wouldn't accept any other command, not even downgrading pip and would ask for Python 3.5 or above for executing any command. I reinstalled Python and choose pip 19.1.1 and it worked.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest uninstalling then re-downloading python with pip pre-installed [https://www.python.org/downloads/[dowload](https://www.python.org/downloads/%5Bdowload) python 3.8.5]

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure what's the problem, so try all of the below until one works.

1. The command `python` and `pip` is for Python 2. Try `python3` and `pip3`.

   `python3 -m pip3 install`
2. Upgrade `pip` with `python3 -m pip install --user --upgrade pip==9.0.3`. This is based on the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49839610/attributeerror-module-pip-has-no-attribute-main/49990889)

Comment: It wouldn't accept any command. I resolved it by uninstalling and reinstalling Python. Thanks

Comment: That's nice to hear :)

Answer (score 0):

you can even try
`python get-pip.py`
this worked for me

if it worked for in the scripts folder

try adding you scripts folder to local environment variables

it will work

Comment: Thank you for your answer and help. The problem resolved with reinstalling Python.