# How to install PIL programmatically using python script

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, easy-install

I am writing a python script that uses PIL library to resize an image.

Is it possible to see whether the user already has PIL installed on his machine, and if not, install it automatically (ask for admin password if needed)?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/installing-python-module-within-code

Comment: Thanks Nsh, good idea. but I don't know if "pip" is installed, how can I install it?

Comment: To see if its installed simply do the import inside a try except, if it throws the exception its not installed.

Answer (score 1):

Install `pip` by running [this](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) setup script, then install Pillow a subset of PIL:

```
pip install Pillow
```

Comment: I ran the script and got the following exception: Installing collected packages: pip
  Exception:
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/var/folders/vh/jcvrl0tx07b8klnvrbklmfmw0000gn/T/tmpq7Xmrd/pip.zip/pip/basecommand.py", line 246, in main
      status = self.run(options, args)
    File "/var/folders/vh/jcvrl0tx07b8klnvrbklmfmw0000gn/T/tmpq7Xmrd/pip.zip/pip/commands/install.py", line 352, in run
      root=options.root_path,
    File "/var/folders/vh/jcvrl0tx07b8klnvrbklmfmw0000gn/T/tmpq7Xmrd/pip.zip/pip/req/req_set.py", line 693, in install
      **kwargs

Comment: File "/var/folders/vh/jcvrl0tx07b8klnvrbklmfmw0000gn/T/tmpq7Xmrd/pip.zip/pip/req/req_install.py", line 817, in install
      self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root)
    File "/var/folders/vh/jcvrl0tx07b8klnvrbklmfmw0000gn/T/tmpq7Xmrd/pip.zip/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1018, in move_wheel_files
      isolated=self.isolated,
    File "/var/folders/vh/jcvrl0tx07b8klnvrbklmfmw0000gn/T/tmpq7Xmrd/pip.zip/pip/wheel.py", line 237, in move_wheel_files
      clobber(source, lib_dir, True)

Comment: File "/var/folders/vh/jcvrl0tx07b8klnvrbklmfmw0000gn/T/tmpq7Xmrd/pip.zip/pip/wheel.py", line 208, in clobber
      os.makedirs(destdir)
    File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/os.py", line 157, in makedirs
      mkdir(name, mode)
  OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip'

Comment: Im soure you know by now, but just for the record, you need to use sudo: `sudo pip install Pillow`.
Also this should be marked as the correct answer since Pillow is a more modern fork of PIL.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi running the script you suggested generated the errors I mentioned, so I can't mark it as an answer.

Comment: @Nili In the command line, enter `sudo apt-get install python-pip`

Comment: Then you enter `pip install Pillow` once you're done with that.