# pip is not responding in python

Tags: python, pandas, installation, pip

I run python 2.7
I did as follow but still receiving the following strange feedback, not sure why.

```
Import pip
pip install pandas
```

can someone explain to me what's the error mean?

[error message I receive trying to install](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fo2b7.png)

Comment: You need to run it on a command line, not in Python.

Comment: (as @ayhan said) but even if you did run it from python be careful of case, its `import`, not `Import`.  You can run `pip` from python code, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/installing-python-module-within-code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pip install pandas` is not a command that you run from within your Python script. It is run at the command line.

---

Alternatively, you can do this from within your code:

```
pip.main(['install', 'pandas'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running `pip` from the command line (bash/terminal on linux/osx or cmd.exe in Windows), not from a python script.
`pip install pandas`

If you're not using [**virtualenv**](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/), you might need administrative privileges.

On Linux/OSX use `sudo`:
`sudo pip install pandas`

On Windows run `Command Prompt` as Administrator:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc947813%28v=ws.10%29.aspx