# Python: Add egg or do pip install from the Jupyter notebook interface

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I am using a Jupyter notebook installed on a server. I am wondering is it possible to upload an egg file, or do a pip install from the notebook interface since I don't want to bother the system administrator for every single package I am experimenting. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Doesn't pip uses local installation by default? I don't think you need administrator/sudo privileges for running pip install in your console.

Comment: You can `pip install --user ...` or setup a virtualenv  and install inside your venv

Comment: Hi, the thing is the attached interface is all I allowed to access. The same config is done for all users ... I am not sure if I could set a vertualenv, and have Jupyter run on that virtualenv just for myself

Answer (score 0):

There is already a page on this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/installing-python-module-within-code).

This is what you should be able to do in the notebook, if you want to install any given 'package':

import pip
pip.main(['install', 'package'])