# Using conda install within a python script

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, conda

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/installing-python-module-within-code?answertab=active#tab-top) you can import pip from within a Python script and use it to install a module. Is it possible to do this with `conda install`?

The conda documentation only shows examples from the command line but I'm looking for code that can be executed from within a Python script.

Yes, I could execute shell commands from within the script but I am trying to avoid this as it is basically assuming that conda cannot be imported and its functions called.

Comment: Why don't you try and report back? :)

Comment: Report what back?

Comment: you can always use subprocess

Comment: Yes, and I can also just use a bash script too but I'd like to avoid executing shell commands from within Python as it seems hackish. It is possible to import pip from within the Python script and install packages and it looks like I can import conda as well. Just don't see how to use conda from within a Python script.

Comment: While it is possible to `import pip` in Python, that is [explicitly discouraged in pip's documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program). I don't see anything hackish about using the public facing API's that pip and conda recommend -- which are based on calling new processes with arguments and option flags. conda now has a Python API that mimics the command line (see @YenForYang's answer). This API did not exist when this question was first posted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was looking at the latest [Conda Python API](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/api/) and noticed that there are actually only 2 public modules with “very long-term stability”:

1. `conda.cli.python_api`
2. `conda.api`

For your question, I would work with the first:

**NOTE**: `run_command()` below will **always** add a `-y`/`--yes` option (i.e. *it will not ask for confirmation*)

```py
import conda.cli.python_api as Conda
import sys

###################################################################################################
# The below is roughly equivalent to:
#   conda install -y 'args-go-here' 'no-whitespace-splitting-occurs' 'square-brackets-optional'

(stdout_str, stderr_str, return_code_int) = Conda.run_command(
    Conda.Commands.INSTALL, # alternatively, you can just say "install"
                            # ...it's probably safer long-term to use the Commands class though
                            # Commands include:
                            #  CLEAN,CONFIG,CREATE,INFO,INSTALL,HELP,LIST,REMOVE,SEARCH,UPDATE,RUN
    [ 'args-go-here', 'no-whitespace-splitting-occurs', 'square-brackets-optional' ],
    use_exception_handler=True,  # Defaults to False, use that if you want to handle your own exceptions
    stdout=sys.stdout, # Defaults to being returned as a str (stdout_str)
    stderr=sys.stderr, # Also defaults to being returned as str (stderr_str)
    search_path=Conda.SEARCH_PATH  # this is the default; adding only for illustrative purposes
)
###################################################################################################
```

---

The nice thing about using the above is that it solves a problem that occurs (mentioned in the comments above) when using `conda.cli.main()`:

> ...conda tried to interpret the comand line arguments instead of the arguments of conda.cli.main(), so using conda.cli.main() like this might not work for some things.

---

The other question in the comments above was:

> How [to install a package] when the channel is not the default?

```py
import conda.cli.python_api as Conda
import sys

###################################################################################################
# Either:
#   conda install -y -c <CHANNEL> <PACKAGE>
# Or (>= conda 4.6)
#   conda install -y <CHANNEL>::<PACKAGE>

(stdout_str, stderr_str, return_code_int) = Conda.run_command(
    Conda.Commands.INSTALL,
    '-c', '<CHANNEL>',
    '<PACKAGE>'
    use_exception_handler=True, stdout=sys.stdout, stderr=sys.stderr
)
###################################################################################################
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. The originally accepted answer relies on an internal API with no guarantee of stability. Also, I think a complete answer should mention calling conda with the `subprocess` module. Calling conda from the `subprocess` module with the `--json` option and parsing the results is perfectly valid and likely even more stable. It also does not require `conda` to be installed in the conda environment. Avoiding `subprocess` for performance reasons is likely premature optimization.

Comment: what is CHANNEL?

Comment: It is stated above the fragment of code... conda has channels which hold recipes for different packages. For example, there is "anaconda" channel, "conda-forge" channel, "defaults" channel, "jetbrains" channel and so on.

Answer (score 23):

You can use `conda.cli.main`. For example, this installs `numpy`:

```
import conda.cli

conda.cli.main('conda', 'install',  '-y', 'numpy')
```

Use the `-y` argument to avoid interactive questions:

> -y, --yes             Do not ask for confirmation.

Comment: Thanks! This did the trick and was exactly what I was looking for. I had seen this in the conda script itself but couldn't decipher how to use it. I was passing a list to it rather than a set of commands.

Comment: I found that when I tried to do this with a script that had command line arguments that conda tried to interpret the comand line arguments instead of the arguments of `conda.cli.main()`, so using `conda.cli.main()` like this might not work for some things.

Comment: How do you do when the channel is not the default?

Comment: @ws_e_c421  See my answer below if you are looking for a solution to that issue (still).

Comment: @pceccon  Simply add the arguments `'-c', '<CHANNEL>'`. See my answer below for an example.

Comment: This is the best short and clean example here.  I find it easy to understand and extend.  However, as @ws_e_c421 above points out, it may not be the best performant if it is executed multiple times in the same Python session, because the conda cache is not flushed until conda exits.

Comment: @RichLysakowskiPhD Isn't caching a good thing in terms of performance? Or, are you concerned about using a lot of memory and therefore slowing things down?

Comment: Caching is good for performance but bad for behavior. I last looked closely at this two years ago when I posted my answer. At that time, `conda` would read and cache the package metadata at start up. If I tried to do multiple installs and removals in a single process, I would run into errors because the in memory cache of metadata was not updated by the new operations. My guess was that the developers only tested performing one package operation per process so invalid metadata was never a problem for their tests. The handling of metadata could have improved in the time since then.

Comment: Here is one example of the caching affecting multiple conda commands in one process. In this case the negative effect is fairly minor -- just that pip packages do not show up for `conda list`: https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/8730

Comment: Good to know. So the `subprocess` approach seems best after all.

Answer (score 6):

Having worked with `conda` from Python scripts for a while now, I think calling `conda` with the `subprocess` module works the best overall. In Python 3.7+, you could do something like this:

```py
import json
from subprocess import run


def conda_list(environment):
    proc = run(["conda", "list", "--json", "--name", environment],
               text=True, capture_output=True)
    return json.loads(proc.stdout)


def conda_install(environment, *package):
    proc = run(["conda", "install", "--quiet", "--name", environment] + packages,
               text=True, capture_output=True)
    return json.loads(proc.stdout)
```

As I pointed out in a comment, `conda.cli.main()` was not intended for external use. It parses `sys.argv` directly, so if you try to use it in your own script with your own command line arguments, they will get fed to `conda.cli.main()` as well.

@YenForYang's answer suggesting `conda.cli.python_api` is better because this is a publicly documented API for calling `conda` commands. However, I have found that it still has rough edges. `conda` builds up internal state as it executes a command (e.g. caches). The way conda is usually used and usually tested is as a command line program. In that case, this internal state is discarded at the end of the `conda` command. With `conda.cli.python_api`, you can execute several `conda` commands within a single process. In this case, the internal state carries over and can sometimes lead to unexpected results (e.g. the cache becomes outdated as commands are performed). Of course, it should be possible for `conda` to handle this internal state directly. My point is just that using `conda` this way is not the main focus of the developers. If you want the most reliable method, use `conda` the way the developers intend it to be used -- as its own process.

`conda` is a fairly slow command, so I don't think one should worry about the performance impact of calling a subprocess. As I noted in another comment, `pip` is a similar tool to `conda` and explicitly states in [its documentation that it should be called as a subprocess, not imported into Python](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program).

Comment: I would like to use your solution but I am running into the issue where it complains about `conda init` not being run. I think it actually reads the source of your bashrc (or whatever) and stops you from continuing. If there is a way on the command line to disable this (its not documented AFAIK) then this is the best way for the reasons you list.

Comment: I usually run `conda activate base` in the environment before running Python scripts that interact with `conda` with `subprocess`. I am not sure what you mean by environment stuff. I use these scripts to interact with conda environments.

Comment: I am using a remote invocation framework (invoke/fabric) which complicates things so that I can't just run `conda activate` beforehand. Re 'environment stuff': I am also trying to automate the creation, destruction, and activation of environments which is not a part of the `conda.cli.python_api`

Comment: That does make it tougher. I usually wrap my Python script in a bash script that uses `conda activate` when I need the conda environment. All `conda activate` does is set environment variables, so you could look at what it does and set them manually. An alternative is to wrap all the conda calls in `conda run` but it is still an `alpha` level feature. With `conda run` try to use as new a version of conda as possible for better support ([one important improvement](https://github.com/conda/conda/pull/9537) is not yet in a release of conda).

Comment: Didn't know about `conda run` but I will definitely keep an eye out on that. Manually setting variables might work as a quick patch, but sounds really fragile for automating stuff.

Answer (score 1):

I found that `conda.cli.python_api` and `conda.api` are limited, in the sense that, they both don't have the option to execute commands like this:

```
conda export env > requirements.txt
```

So instead I used subprocess with the flag `shell=True` to get the job done.

```
subprocess.run(f"conda env export --name {env} > {file_path_from_history}",shell=True)
```

where `env` is the name of the env to be saved to `requirements.txt`.

Comment: I would like to programmatically export an environment to a requirements.txt file.   But what is the correct value of 'file_path_from_history' supposed to be here?  I get a "NameError: name 'file_path_from_history' is not defined" message when I run your command.

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
!conda install xyzpackage
```

Please remember this has to be done within the Python script not the OS prompt.

Or else you could try the following:

```
import sys
from conda.cli import main

    sys.exit(main())

    try:
        import conda
        from conda.cli import main
        sys.argv = ['conda'] + list(args)
        main()
```

Comment: This seems hackish as it is executing a shell command. I'd like to import conda and call its equivalent install function.

Comment: Check the above link out which gives info on conda and python modules. Conda is an environment and a utility which is available in the OS and not inside python module. Is there any specific anaconda package that you have in mind?

Comment: Please see the answer by @mike-muller as, in fact, you `can` access conda from within a Python script.

Comment: This is a hack, but it works.  Use it in limited doses, and understand the ramifications !!

Answer (score -2):

The simpler thing that i tried and worked for me was :

```
import os

try:
    import graphviz
except:
    print ("graphviz not found, Installing graphviz ")
    os.system("conda install -c anaconda graphviz")
    import graphviz
```

And make sure you run your script as admin.

Comment: You shouldn't have to rely on admin permissions for anything with conda (unless it is distributed via your OS package manager of which there are none that I am aware of). Also goes against the request of the question.