# Python script creates conda env inside the current conda env

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

Following [these suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41767340/using-conda-install-within-a-python-script) and [these instructions](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/api/python_api.html) I want to create a conda environment `bar` from within a Python script. My problem is that I run the script while activated another env `foo`. As in the examples from the docs - the commands work, however my new env is created under the current one, like here:

```
base                     MYHOME/miniconda3
foo                   *  MYHOME/miniconda3/envs/foo
                         MYHOME/miniconda3/envs/foo/envs/bar
```

Is there any way to make it top level and thus its name recognised by *conda*?

My command in the script (as in the docs) is:
`run_command(Commands.CREATE, "-n", "bar", "python=3", "flask")`

Comment: Please write this up as reproducible steps rather than descriptive prose. Create a `foo` (presumbaly with python), activate it, include a simple script, the command to run it, and`conda env list` before and after.

Comment: I have asked another question which seems linked to this one, possibly solving that one first would lead us to a solution here. Mind taking a look? 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74321787/conda-info-points-to-a-different-base-path-while-called-from-within-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not really a matter of `conda.cli`. As discussed in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74321787/conda-info-points-to-a-different-base-path-while-called-from-within-python): the issue was that `foo` env contained `conda` itself inside it and while building the environment from within the script the interpreter called that "internal" conda, thus thinking that `foo` is `base`.