# `conda info` points to a different base path while called from within Python

Tags: python, shell, conda

I have observed a strange behaviour:

1. In my shell I activate a *conda* environment `abc` with `conda activate abc`.
2. I run `conda info --base` and obtain a proper path where I installed conda, I get: `$HOME/miniconda3`.
3. I start a *python* interpreter with `python`
4. In the interpreter I run: `import os` and `os.system("conda info --base")` and this time I get: `$HOME/miniconda3/envs/abc`, as if the shell from within python believes that the environment which started the interpreter is base now.

Why is this happening? Is there any way to obtain path to the *real* `base` environment from within Python?

#### Comment replies

I just created a the env once again and now the problem is gone... `abc` is a clean env:

```
(base) [maciek]$ conda list -n abc
# packages in environment at ***/miniconda3/envs/abc:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
```

However, the problematic env had:

```
# packages in environment at ***/miniconda3/envs/abc-old:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                 conda_forge    conda-forge
_openmp_mutex             4.5                       2_gnu    conda-forge
_r-mutex                  1.0.0               anacondar_1    conda-forge
alsa-lib                  1.2.6.1              h7f98852_0    conda-forge
anyio                     3.6.1            py39hf3d152e_0    conda-forge
argon2-cffi               21.3.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
argon2-cffi-bindings      21.2.0           py39hb9d737c_2    conda-forge
arpack                    3.7.0                hdefa2d7_2    conda-forge
asttokens                 2.0.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
atk-1.0                   2.36.0               h3371d22_4    conda-forge
attrs                     21.4.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
babel                     2.9.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
backcall                  0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
bash                      5.0.018              h14c3975_0    anaconda
bash_kernel               0.7.2            py39hf3d152e_4    conda-forge
beautifulsoup4            4.11.1             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
binutils_impl_linux-64    2.36.1               h193b22a_2    conda-forge
binutils_linux-64         2.36                hf3e587d_10    conda-forge
black                     22.6.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
bleach                    4.1.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
boa                       0.11.0             pyha770c72_4    conda-forge
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py39hb9d737c_1004    conda-forge
bwidget                   1.9.14               ha770c72_1    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.8                h7b6447c_0    anaconda
c-ares                    1.18.1               h7f98852_0    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2022.9.24            ha878542_0    conda-forge
cairo                     1.16.0            ha12eb4b_1010    conda-forge
certifi                   2022.9.24          pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
cffi                      1.15.1           py39he91dace_0    conda-forge
chardet                   5.0.0            py39hf3d152e_0    conda-forge
charset-normalizer        2.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
chrpath                   0.16              h7f98852_1002    conda-forge
clang_variant             1.0                  cling_v0.7    conda-forge
clangdev                  5.0.0             ha35fd46_1011    conda-forge
click                     8.1.3            py39hf3d152e_0    conda-forge
cling                     0.7                  hf817b99_3    conda-forge
colorama                  0.4.5              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
commonmark                0.9.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
conda                     4.14.0           py39hf3d152e_0    conda-forge
conda-build               3.22.0           py39hf3d152e_2    conda-forge
conda-package-handling    1.9.0            py39hb9d737c_0    conda-forge
coverage                  6.4.2            py39hb9d737c_0    conda-forge
cppzmq                    4.7.1                hf7cf922_2    conda-forge
cryptography              37.0.4           py39hd97740a_0    conda-forge
curl                      7.83.1               h7bff187_0    conda-forge
dataclasses               0.8                pyh6d0b6a4_7    anaconda
dbus                      1.13.18              hb2f20db_0    anaconda
debugpy                   1.6.0            py39h5a03fae_0    conda-forge
decorator                 5.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
entrypoints               0.4                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
executing                 0.8.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
expat                     2.4.8                h27087fc_0    conda-forge
fftw                      3.3.10          nompi_h77c792f_102    conda-forge
filelock                  3.8.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
flake8                    4.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_2    conda-forge
fltk                      1.3.8                h83e168f_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-dejavu-sans-mono 2.37                 hab24e00_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-inconsolata      3.000                h77eed37_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-source-code-pro  2.038                h77eed37_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-ubuntu           0.83                 hab24e00_0    conda-forge
fontconfig                2.13.96              ha180cfb_0    conda-forge
fonts-conda-ecosystem     1                             0    conda-forge
fonts-conda-forge         1                             0    conda-forge
freetype                  2.11.0               h70c0345_0    anaconda
fribidi                   1.0.10               h7b6447c_0    anaconda
future                    0.18.2           py39h06a4308_1    anaconda
gcc_impl_linux-64         9.4.0               h03d3576_16    conda-forge
gcc_linux-64              9.4.0               h391b98a_10    conda-forge
gdk-pixbuf                2.42.8               hff1cb4f_0    conda-forge
gettext                   0.21.0               hf68c758_0    anaconda
gfortran_impl_linux-64    9.4.0               h0003116_16    conda-forge
gfortran_linux-64         9.4.0               hf0ab688_10    conda-forge
ghostscript               9.54.0               h27087fc_2    conda-forge
giflib                    5.2.1                h36c2ea0_2    conda-forge
git                       2.34.1          pl5262hc120c5b_0    anaconda
gl2ps                     1.4.2                h0708190_0    conda-forge
glib                      2.72.1               h6239696_0    conda-forge
glib-tools                2.72.1               h6239696_0    conda-forge
glob2                     0.7                        py_0    anaconda
glpk                      4.65              h9202a9a_1004    conda-forge
gmp                       6.2.1                h58526e2_0    conda-forge
gnuplot                   5.4.3                hedd7fda_0    conda-forge
graphicsmagick            1.3.37               hdc87540_0    conda-forge
graphite2                 1.3.14               h295c915_1    anaconda
gsl                       2.7                  he838d99_0    conda-forge
gst-plugins-base          1.20.3               hf6a322e_0    conda-forge
gstreamer                 1.20.3               hd4edc92_0    conda-forge
gtk2                      2.24.33              h539f30e_1    conda-forge
gxx_impl_linux-64         9.4.0               h03d3576_16    conda-forge
gxx_linux-64              9.4.0               h0316aca_10    conda-forge
harfbuzz                  3.4.0                hb4a5f5f_0    conda-forge
hdf5                      1.12.1          nompi_h2386368_104    conda-forge
icu                       69.1                 h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
idna                      3.3                pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
importlib-metadata        4.11.4           py39hf3d152e_0    conda-forge
importlib_metadata        4.11.4               hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
importlib_resources       5.8.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
iniconfig                 1.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
ipykernel                 6.15.1             pyh210e3f2_0    conda-forge
ipyparallel               8.4.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ipython                   8.4.0            py39hf3d152e_0    conda-forge
ipython_genutils          0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1    anaconda
ipywidgets                7.6.5              pyhd3eb1b0_1    anaconda
jedi                      0.18.1           py39hf3d152e_1    conda-forge
jinja2                    3.0.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
joblib                    1.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jpeg                      9e                   h7f8727e_0    anaconda
json5                     0.9.6              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
jsonschema                4.7.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter                   1.0.0            py39hf3d152e_7    conda-forge
jupyter_client            7.3.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_console           6.4.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
jupyter_core              4.10.0           py39hf3d152e_0    conda-forge
jupyter_server            1.18.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab                3.4.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2                      py_0    anaconda
jupyterlab_server         2.15.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_widgets        1.0.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1    anaconda
kernel-headers_linux-64   2.6.32              he073ed8_15    conda-forge
keyutils                  1.6.1                h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
krb5                      1.19.3               h3790be6_0    conda-forge
ld_impl_linux-64          2.36.1               hea4e1c9_2    conda-forge
lerc                      3.0                  h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
libarchive                3.5.2                hccf745f_1    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0           13_linux64_openblas    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0           13_linux64_openblas    conda-forge
libclang                  13.0.1          default_hc23dcda_0    conda-forge
libcurl                   7.83.1               h7bff187_0    conda-forge
libdeflate                1.12                 h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
libedit                   3.1.20191231         he28a2e2_2    conda-forge
libev                     4.33                 h516909a_1    conda-forge
libevent                  2.1.10               h9b69904_4    conda-forge
libffi                    3.4.2                h295c915_4    anaconda
libflac                   1.3.4                h27087fc_0    conda-forge
libgcc                    7.2.0                h69d50b8_2    anaconda
libgcc-devel_linux-64     9.4.0               hd854feb_16    conda-forge
libgcc-ng                 12.1.0              h8d9b700_16    conda-forge
libgd                     2.3.3                h283352f_2    conda-forge
libgfortran-ng            12.1.0              h69a702a_16    conda-forge
libgfortran5              12.1.0              hdcd56e2_16    conda-forge
libglib                   2.72.1               h2d90d5f_0    conda-forge
libglu                    9.0.0             he1b5a44_1001    conda-forge
libgomp                   12.1.0              h8d9b700_16    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.16                 h7f8727e_2    anaconda
liblapack                 3.9.0           13_linux64_openblas    conda-forge
liblapacke                3.9.0           13_linux64_openblas    conda-forge
liblief                   0.12.2               h27087fc_0    conda-forge
libllvm13                 13.0.1               hf817b99_2    conda-forge
libmamba                  0.25.0               hd8a31e3_2    conda-forge
libmambapy                0.25.0           py39hd55135b_2    conda-forge
libnghttp2                1.47.0               h727a467_0    conda-forge
libnsl                    2.0.0                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
libogg                    1.3.4                h7f98852_1    conda-forge
libopenblas               0.3.18          pthreads_h8fe5266_0    conda-forge
libopus                   1.3.1                h7f98852_1    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.37               hbc83047_0    anaconda
libpq                     14.3                 hd77ab85_0    conda-forge
libsanitizer              9.4.0               h79bfe98_16    conda-forge
libsndfile                1.0.31               h9c3ff4c_1    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.18               h7b6447c_0    anaconda
libsolv                   0.7.22               h6239696_0    conda-forge
libssh2                   1.10.0               ha56f1ee_2    conda-forge
libstdcxx-devel_linux-64  9.4.0               hd854feb_16    conda-forge
libstdcxx-ng              12.1.0              ha89aaad_16    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.4.0                hc85c160_1    conda-forge
libuuid                   2.32.1            h7f98852_1000    conda-forge
libvorbis                 1.3.7                h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
libwebp                   1.2.2                h3452ae3_0    conda-forge
libwebp-base              1.2.2                h7f8727e_0    anaconda
libxcb                    1.13              h7f98852_1004    conda-forge
libxkbcommon              1.0.3                he3ba5ed_0    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.9.12               h885dcf4_1    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.12               h166bdaf_2    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.9.3                h295c915_1    anaconda
lzo                       2.10              h516909a_1000    conda-forge
make                      4.3                  hd18ef5c_1    conda-forge
mamba                     0.25.0           py39hfa8f2c8_2    conda-forge
markupsafe                2.1.1            py39hb9d737c_1    conda-forge
matplotlib-inline         0.1.2              pyhd3eb1b0_2    anaconda
mccabe                    0.6.1                      py_1    conda-forge
metakernel                0.29.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
metis                     5.1.0             h58526e2_1006    conda-forge
mistune                   0.8.4           py39h3811e60_1005    conda-forge
mpfr                      4.1.0                h9202a9a_1    conda-forge
mypy                      0.941            py39hb9d737c_0    conda-forge
mypy_extensions           0.4.3            py39hf3d152e_5    conda-forge
mysql-common              8.0.29               haf5c9bc_1    conda-forge
mysql-libs                8.0.29               h28c427c_1    conda-forge
nbclassic                 0.3.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
nbclient                  0.6.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nbconvert                 6.5.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nbconvert-core            6.5.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nbconvert-pandoc          6.5.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nbformat                  5.4.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.3                  h27087fc_1    conda-forge
nest-asyncio              1.5.5              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nlohmann_json             3.9.1                h9c3ff4c_1    conda-forge
notebook                  6.4.12             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
nspr                      4.32                 h9c3ff4c_1    conda-forge
nss                       3.78                 h2350873_0    conda-forge
octave                    7.1.0                h8cb3778_1    conda-forge
octave_kernel             0.34.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1s               h166bdaf_0    conda-forge
packaging                 21.3               pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
pandoc                    2.18                 ha770c72_0    conda-forge
pandocfilters             1.5.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
pango                     1.48.10              h4dcc4a0_3    conda-forge
parso                     0.8.3              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
patch                     2.7.6             h7f98852_1002    conda-forge
patchelf                  0.15.0               h58526e2_0    conda-forge
pathspec                  0.9.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pcre                      8.45                 h295c915_0    anaconda
pcre2                     10.37                h032f7d1_0    conda-forge
perl                      5.32.1          2_h7f98852_perl5    conda-forge
pexpect                   4.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_3    anaconda
pickleshare               0.7.5           pyhd3eb1b0_1003    anaconda
pip                       22.1.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pixman                    0.40.0               h7f8727e_1    anaconda
pkginfo                   1.8.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
platformdirs              2.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
pluggy                    1.0.0            py39hf3d152e_3    conda-forge
ply                       3.11                       py_1    conda-forge
portalocker               2.5.1            py39hf3d152e_0    conda-forge
portaudio                 19.6.0               h57a0ea0_5    conda-forge
prometheus_client         0.13.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
prompt-toolkit            3.0.20             pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
prompt_toolkit            3.0.20               hd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
psutil                    5.9.1            py39hb9d737c_0    conda-forge
pthread-stubs             0.4               h36c2ea0_1001    conda-forge
ptyprocess                0.7.0              pyhd3eb1b0_2    anaconda
pugixml                   1.11.4               h295c915_1    anaconda
pure_eval                 0.2.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
py                        1.11.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
py-lief                   0.12.2           py39h5a03fae_0    conda-forge
pybind11-abi              4                    hd8ed1ab_3    conda-forge
pycodestyle               2.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
pycosat                   0.6.3           py39hb9d737c_1010    conda-forge
pycparser                 2.21               pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
pydocstyle                6.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyflakes                  2.4.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
pygments                  2.11.2             pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
pyopenssl                 22.0.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
pyparsing                 3.0.4              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
pyqt                      5.12.3           py39hf3d152e_7    conda-forge
pyqt-impl                 5.12.3           py39h0fcd23e_7    conda-forge
pyqt5-sip                 4.19.18          py39he80948d_7    conda-forge
pyqtchart                 5.12             py39h0fcd23e_7    conda-forge
pyqtwebengine             5.12.1           py39h0fcd23e_7    conda-forge
pyrsistent                0.18.1           py39hb9d737c_1    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.1            py39hf3d152e_5    conda-forge
pytest                    7.1.2            py39hf3d152e_0    conda-forge
python                    3.9.13          h9a8a25e_0_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
python-fastjsonschema     2.15.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
python-libarchive-c       4.0              py39hf3d152e_1    conda-forge
python_abi                3.9                      2_cp39    conda-forge
pytz                      2022.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyyaml                    6.0              py39hb9d737c_4    conda-forge
pyzmq                     23.2.0           py39headdf64_0    conda-forge
qhull                     2020.2               h4bd325d_2    conda-forge
qscintilla2               2.11.2           py39h5a03fae_6    conda-forge
qt                        5.12.9               h1304e3e_6    conda-forge
qtconsole                 5.3.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
qtconsole-base            5.3.1              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
qtpy                      2.0.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
r-base                    4.1.2                hde4fec0_0    conda-forge
r-base64enc               0.1_3           r41hcfec24a_1004    conda-forge
r-cli                     3.3.0             r41h7525677_0    conda-forge
r-crayon                  1.5.1             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-digest                  0.6.29            r41h03ef668_0    conda-forge
r-ellipsis                0.3.2             r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-evaluate                0.15              r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-fansi                   1.0.3             r41h06615bd_0    conda-forge
r-fastmap                 1.1.0             r41h03ef668_0    conda-forge
r-glue                    1.6.2             r41h06615bd_0    conda-forge
r-htmltools               0.5.3             r41h7525677_0    conda-forge
r-irdisplay               1.1               r41hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
r-irkernel                1.3               r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-jsonlite                1.8.0             r41h06615bd_0    conda-forge
r-lifecycle               1.0.1             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-magrittr                2.0.3             r41h06615bd_0    conda-forge
r-pbdzmq                  0.3_7             r41h42bf92c_0    conda-forge
r-pillar                  1.8.0             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-repr                    1.1.4             r41h785f33e_0    conda-forge
r-rlang                   1.0.4             r41h7525677_0    conda-forge
r-rzmq                    0.9.8             r41h42bf92c_0    conda-forge
r-stringi                 1.7.6             r41h337692f_1    conda-forge
r-stringr                 1.4.0             r41hc72bb7e_2    conda-forge
r-utf8                    1.2.2             r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-uuid                    1.1_0             r41h06615bd_0    conda-forge
r-vctrs                   0.4.1             r41h7525677_0    conda-forge
readline                  8.1                  h46c0cb4_0    conda-forge
reproc                    14.2.4               h295c915_1    anaconda
reproc-cpp                14.2.4               h295c915_1    anaconda
requests                  2.28.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
rich                      12.6.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
ripgrep                   13.0.0               h2f28480_2    conda-forge
ruamel.yaml               0.17.21          py39hb9d737c_1    conda-forge
ruamel.yaml.clib          0.2.6            py39h7f8727e_0    anaconda
ruamel_yaml               0.15.80         py39hb9d737c_1007    conda-forge
sed                       4.8                  he412f7d_0    conda-forge
send2trash                1.8.0              pyhd3eb1b0_1    anaconda
seshat                    0.2.0                    pypi_0    pypi
setuptools                63.2.0           py39hf3d152e_0    conda-forge
shellingham               1.3.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
sip                       6.6.2            py39h5a03fae_0    conda-forge
six                       1.16.0             pyhd3eb1b0_1    anaconda
sniffio                   1.2.0            py39hf3d152e_3    conda-forge
snowballstemmer           2.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
soupsieve                 2.3.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
sqlite                    3.38.5               hc218d9a_0    anaconda
stack_data                0.2.0              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
suitesparse               5.10.1               h9e50725_1    conda-forge
sundials                  6.2.0                h1b77dab_0    conda-forge
sysroot_linux-64          2.12                he073ed8_15    conda-forge
tbb                       2021.5.0             h924138e_1    conda-forge
terminado                 0.15.0           py39hf3d152e_0    conda-forge
testpath                  0.6.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
texinfo                   6.8             pl5321h46c0cb4_1    conda-forge
tinycss2                  1.1.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.12               h1ccaba5_0    anaconda
tktable                   2.10                 hb7b940f_3    conda-forge
toml                      0.10.2             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tomli                     2.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
toolz                     0.12.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tornado                   6.2              py39hb9d737c_0    conda-forge
tqdm                      4.64.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
traitlets                 5.1.1              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
typed-ast                 1.5.4            py39hb9d737c_0    conda-forge
typer                     0.4.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
types-toml                0.10.8             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing-extensions         4.1.1                hd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
typing_extensions         4.1.1              pyh06a4308_0    anaconda
tzdata                    2022a                hda174b7_0    anaconda
urllib3                   1.26.10            pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
watchgod                  0.8.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
webencodings              0.5.1                      py_1    conda-forge
websocket-client          1.3.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.37.1             pyhd3eb1b0_0    anaconda
widgetsnbextension        3.5.2            py39hf3d152e_1    conda-forge
xeus                      0.25.3               h78d96c3_1    conda-forge
xeus-cling                0.11.0               h5a79028_0    conda-forge
xorg-fixesproto           5.0               h7f98852_1002    conda-forge
xorg-kbproto              1.0.7             h7f98852_1002    conda-forge
xorg-libice               1.0.10               h7f98852_0    conda-forge
xorg-libsm                1.2.3             hd9c2040_1000    conda-forge
xorg-libx11               1.7.2                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxau               1.0.9                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxdmcp             1.1.3                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxext              1.3.4                h7f98852_1    conda-forge
xorg-libxfixes            5.0.3             h7f98852_1004    conda-forge
xorg-libxrender           0.9.10            h7f98852_1003    conda-forge
xorg-libxt                1.2.1                h7f98852_2    conda-forge
xorg-renderproto          0.11.1            h7f98852_1002    conda-forge
xorg-xextproto            7.3.0             h7f98852_1002    conda-forge
xorg-xproto               7.0.31            h7f98852_1007    conda-forge
xtl                       0.6.23               h4bd325d_1    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.5                h7f8727e_1    anaconda
yaml                      0.2.5                h7f98852_2    conda-forge
yaml-cpp                  0.7.0                h295c915_1    anaconda
zeromq                    4.3.4                h2531618_0    anaconda
zipp                      3.8.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.12               h7f8727e_2    anaconda
zstd                      1.5.2                ha4553b6_0    anaconda
```

Comment: I cannot reproduce this - we need more info. Any chance you are manually adding `miniconda3/bin` to PATH in your `.bashrc` (or other shell init)? Maybe show us the Conda sections in the shell init file. What packages are installed in `abc`? `conda` perhaps? (add `conda list -n abc` to the question body)

Comment: Done. Yes, `conda` was installed in the `abc` env. Is that a problem? Pyyhon called the internal one instead of external one?

Comment: Yes, exactly - and thanks for adding the extra info. I was able to recreate afterall using a simple environment with `conda` installed. Remove it. BTW, I see mixtures of **anaconda** and **conda-forge** channel packages. Just use one. If you need a **conda-forge** package, then only use **conda-forge** for all packages - it is a standalone system these days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can only reproduce this behavior in the case that the **abc** environment has the `conda` package installed.

```bash
$ mamba create -yn foo python
$ mamba run -n foo python -c 'import os; os.system("conda info --base")'
/Users/mfansler/miniconda3

$ mamba create -yn bar conda
$ mamba run -n bar python -c 'import os; os.system("conda info --base")'
/Users/mfansler/miniconda3/envs/bar
```

The `conda` package should only ever be installed in **base**. One should generally not use **base** for development, and subsequently, it shouldn't really be used to `conda clone` new environments. which may be how **abc** was created in OP.

Removing the `conda` package should end this aberrant behavior.