# Shipping Code With Additional Python Module To Install

Tags: python, module

I've a python script to be executed on N systems, but some of them might be Python 2.4 and do not include `json` module.

I've found `simplejson` module compatible with Python 2.4 in tar.gz form, is it possible to ship the module together with the script and having it installed on the fly?

For example:

```
try:
   import json
except:
   sys.out('old version found, going to install simplejson')
   installing simplejson.....?
   import simplejson as json
```

Part II: how to install the package w/o PIP?

Comment: Yes,why not? unless the user gives permission to do so

Comment: @bigbounty cool, didn't know it's common scenario.

Comment: with respect to pip, use pip/pip3 install packagename

Comment: @bigbounty there is no pip on the system, so I need an alternative way.

Comment: sudo apt-get install python-pip/pip3 in ubuntu, For windows,refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows

Comment: @bigbounty no access external network.

Answer (score -1):

The easiest thing would be to only import `simplejson`, and then make sure  you use the Py2.4-compatible version in all your environments (I'm assuming the python version can't be upgraded).

If you still want to install simplejson on the fly, I would look at the following SO thread:

[Installing python module within code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/installing-python-module-within-code)

Hopefully you can setup those systems to have pip (since you would be adding this script and running it in these systems, I'm assuming you have write and execute permissions).