# Pycharm pandas_datareader not found

Tags: python, pandas-datareader

I am creating a stock exchange monitor in python, and have had problems with the pandas_datareader module. The original module in the code was pandas.io.data, but an amendment has been made as pandas no longer supports this module. Here is the code;

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader as web   
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2016, 1, 1)
end = datetime.date.today()

apple = web.DataReader("AAPL", "yahoo", start, end)

type(apple)
```

This code comes with the error;

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/euanoflynn/anaconda/tests/Tests.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pandas_datareader as web   # Package and modules for importing data; this code may change depending on pandas version
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas_datareader'
```

I feel like I'm doing something wrong.

I can post more information if need be.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Have you checked that the module `pandas_datareader` is installed? You can verify by running the command `pip show pandas_datareader` in a command shell. If it does not return any output, you can install with `pip install pandas_datareader` from the command shell as well.

If you want to install the missing package directly in a script, you have to modify your script by adding to your script, after the last `import` line:

```
import pip
pip.main(['install', 'pandas_datareader'])
```

as indicated in [Installing python module within code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/installing-python-module-within-code)

I verified that the example works, but you may want to know that some people experience intermittent issues with the price scraping API, as per https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/170

Comment: This is the result;   `pip show pandas_datareader
  File "<ipython-input-2-155e3cc1be26>", line 1
    pip show pandas_datareader
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax1`

Comment: And for the other... `pip install pandas_datareader
  File "<ipython-input-3-16663e45080a>", line 1
    pip install pandas_datareader
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: you have to run those commands in a shell, not in the python interpreter. If you want to can install from within the interpreter using the pip module. I will edit my answer to include this option.