# How to check and install missing modules in Python at time of execution

Tags: python

I am working on a Python program which will be distributed to our clients.

Their requirement is that the program should take care of everything without their manual intervention.

How do I check and install missing modules in Python at the time of executing the code? In R, I can use the code as provided below.

How do I replicate something similar in Python?

```
# Check and install missing packages in R
list.of.packages <- c("RDCOMClient", "htmlTable")
new.packages <- list.of.packages[!(list.of.packages %in% installed.packages()[,"Package"])]
if(length(new.packages) > 0) {
  install.packages(new.packages)
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15950647/8171079 ?

Comment: Thanks @user8171079. This worked for me. Only question I have is how do I test multiple modules?

Answer (score 5):

Use exception handling, then `pip` to install the modules:

```
import pip

def install(package):
    pip.main(['install', package])

def install_all_packages(modules_to_try):
    for module in modules_to_try:
        try:
           __import__(module)        
        except ImportError as e:
            install(e.name)
```

Note: the `__import__` built-in imports modules by a string name. A probably better way to do this is to use the [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) module, for example `importlib.import_module`

Comment: Your code doesn't work if user doesn't have superuser permission: PermissionError

Comment: Hello rassar, I tried the above solution. But it does not seem to be working for me for some reason. I even tried changing the `install(e.name)` to `install('e.name')` but that too does not seem to work. Any idea what I might be doing wrong? I am using Python 3.6. I am new to Python by the way. Most of my work is in R.

Comment: This is the error message - `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\KING\Desktop\Test.py", line 6, in <module>
    for module in modules_to_try:
NameError: name 'modules_to_try' is not defined`

Comment: That's just a variable placeholder. Replace it with the list of modules you need to install. Run the function `install_all_packages` and pass it as an argument.

Answer (score 0):

You can use exception handling:

```
try:
    import some_module

except ImportError as e:
    print(e)
    # install module or some operation
```

Comment: This will require the user to type in every single module that they want to import. The `__import__` function, or `importlib.import_module` is better in this case.

Comment: Ok, I understood this way is not much efficient but it's not wrong!