# Check and install 'win32com.client' module at time of execution in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, win32com

I am new to Python. I am trying to write a program where I have to check and install any missing modules at the time of execution of the code. I am using the below code provided in the solution  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/installing-python-module-within-code/15950647#15950647).

```
# Code to check and install missing modules

import pip

# Define function to install missing modules

def install(package):
    pip.main(['install', package])

# Call funtion and install missing module

if __name__ == '__main__':
    install('win32com.client')
```

When I try executing this, I get the below message. Even when I tried replacing `install('win32com.client')` by `install('win32com')`, I still get a similar message. The code works if I used it to check and install `pandas` module.

```
Collecting win32com.client
[31m  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement win32com.client (from versions: )[0m
[31mNo matching distribution found for win32com.client[0m
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I install the `win32com.client` module using the code I have provided above? This needs to be checked and installed at the time of execution and should have no manual intervention. I am using Python 3.6.4 and my OS is Windows x64 bit. Any guidance on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try `install('pypiwin32')` instead of `install('win32com.client')`

Comment: I was successfully able to install the module `pypiwin32` using `install('pypiwin32')`. But when I try to `import win32com.client`, I get the message ``from pypiwin32 import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pypiwin32'``. Not sure if it worked.

Comment: @Code_Sipra `pypiwin32` is not a module name, it's only a name of a PYPI entry. You need to import `win32com.client`.