# QPython3 on Android 7.1 - Can not install packages using pip

Tags: android, python, python-3.x, qpython3

I am trying to run a python code on my Android 7.1 mobile using QPython3 app. I clicked on the "Menu" tab and then "Run script" option. Out of many programs, I opened "pip_console.py" and typed

```
pip install pandas
```

This gives me error -

```
AtrributeError: 'Distribution' object has no attribute '_egg_fetcher'
```

This is true in case of any other module as well. Just to make sure that I am using the latest version, I ran

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

but this also fails and gives an error that

```
it can not open /sdcard/qpython/lib.. directory
```

I am not sure whether this app was properly installed and whether this is the right way to install modules. Can someone please help ?

Thanks,

Sanket.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pip in code as specified by this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/installing-python-module-within-code).

You can do it like this:

> import pip
>
> pip.main(['install','pandas'])

Comment: Sorry that I did not mention it earlier, but I have already tried pip.main(['install','pandas']) and it gives me exactly same error - AtrributeError: 'Distribution' object has no attribute '_egg_fetcher'

Comment: In the description mentioned for qpython3 on play store it is specified that the "It is the only Python interpreter which works under android 4.0 in google play" while you are running android 7.1. Might be some permission issues.