# How can I install 'pandas' and 'numpy' using code?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I already have `pip` installed but I tried this code to install pandas in my Python27/Lib:

```
import os
os.system('pip install pandas')
```

and the tried samples here in :
[Installing python module within code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/installing-python-module-within-code)

and also tried the `setup.py` here in :https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas

but this doesn't download pandas and numpy in my Python27/Lib any answers?

**UPDATE:**

I tried this: and currently installed pandas in my Python

```
try: import pandas
except ImportError:
    from pip._internal import main as pip
    pip(['install', '--user', 'pandas'])
    import pandas
```

but I have this error:

```
[33mYou are using pip version 18.0, however version 18.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.[0m

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\OJT\scanner\install.py", line 5, in <module>
    import pandas
ImportError: No module named pandas
```

Is there a way to install the updated version of pip?

Comment: This question was previously discussed, already:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/installing-python-module-within-code

Comment: I already tried that link, can't you see my question?

Comment: "Is there a way to install the updated version of pip?" - The answer is there already: `pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Does it work to install pandas via the command line? Hint: Check the paths of your python session, for example with `import site; site.getsitepackages()` and compare with `python -m site`. Also, make pip print extra debug information with some verbose flag.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) module in the standard library:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["pip", "install", "pandas"])
```

Comment: WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Comment: I can't test it, I don't have Windows, but do you have pip installed? [instruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750806/how-do-i-install-pip-on-windows)