# python3 subprocess pip "ImportError: cannot import name main" in terminal

Tags: python, terminal, pip, subprocess, ubuntu-16.04

I created a script (see below) to upgrade all my pip packages. I successfully executed my script via `idle3`, i.e. open the script using `idle3` and pressing `F5` to run the script as a module. However, I am not able to execute it in the terminal; got the below error. **How do I overcome this error?** Why does the import error happen in terminal but not in `idle3`?

```
$ python3 -m upgrade_pip_packages 
====================================================
UPGRADING ALL --USER PIP PACKAGES TO LATEST VERSION:
====================================================
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 9, in <module>
    from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main
ERROR: Command 'pip list' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

My script : **upgrade_pip_packages.py**

```
#!/bin/python3
import subprocess
from pprint import pprint


def get_pkgs():
    try:
        cmd = 'pip list'
        completed = subprocess.run( cmd, shell=True, check=True,
                                    stdout=subprocess.PIPE )
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as err:
        print( 'ERROR:', err )
    else:
        for line in completed.stdout.decode('utf-8').splitlines()[2:]:
            yield line


def update_pkgs(piplist):
    npackages = 0
    nupgrades = 0
    nerrors = 0
    upgradelist = []
    errorlist = []
    for i in piplist:
        npackages += 1
        pkgname, ver = i.split()
        print('\n',pkgname)
        try:
            cmd = 'pip install --user {} --upgrade'.format(pkgname)
            completed = subprocess.run( cmd, shell=True, check=True,
                                        stdout=subprocess.PIPE )
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as err:
            nerrors += 1
            errorlist.append(pkgname)
            print( 'ERROR: {}'.format(err) )
        else:
            for line in completed.stdout.decode('utf-8').splitlines():
                print(line)
                if 'Successfully installed' in line:
                    nupgrades +=1
                    upgradelist.append(pkgname)
    return npackages, nupgrades, nerrors, upgradelist, errorlist


def main():
    print('====================================================')
    print('UPGRADING ALL --USER PIP PACKAGES TO LATEST VERSION:')
    print('====================================================')
    pip_pkgs = get_pkgs() # created a generator
    npackages, nupgrades, nerrors, upgradelist, errorlist \
               = update_pkgs(pip_pkgs)
    print('\nNo. of --user pip packages = {}'.format(npackages))
    print('No. of upgrades            = {}'.format(nupgrades))
    print('No. of upgrade errors      = {}'.format(nerrors))
    if upgradelist:
        print('Package(s) upgraded:')
        pprint(upgradelist)
    if errorlist:
        print('Package(s) with upgrade error:')
        pprint(errorlist)
    print()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Final [upgrade_pip_packages.py](https://github.com/sunbearc22/upgrade_pip_packages).

I found the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50255019/5722359) to my question. Essentially, my script had to:

```
import sys
```

and make the following amendments:

```
cmd = [sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'list'] #Change here
completed = subprocess.run( cmd,
                            #shell=True, #switch this off
                            check=True,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE )
```

and

```
cmd = [sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', '--user', pkgname, '--upgrade'] #Change here
completed = subprocess.run( cmd,
                            #shell=True, #switch this off
                            check=True,
                            stdout=subprocess.PIPE )
```

[PyPA documentation](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/?highlight=!%7Bsys.executable%7D#ensure-you-can-run-python-from-the-command-line) explanation:

> It’s recommended to write {sys.executable} rather than plain python in
>   order to ensure that commands are run in the Python installation
>   matching the currently running notebook (which may not be the same
>   Python installation that the python command refers to).

```
$ pip --version
pip 18.1 from ~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip (python 3.5)
$ pip3 --version
pip 18.1 from ~/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip (python 3.5)
```