# using pip search inside a python script

Tags: python, pip, pypi

in a short format, I'm preparing a python script to search all required dependencies in a private pypi repo

if all dependencies exist in the repo, the script tops, if not it builds them and pushes them to the pypi repo

I have seen some examples using:

`search_command = pip.commands.search.SearchCommand()
 options, _ = search_command.parse_args([name, "--index", publish_pypi_simple_url])
pypi_hits = search_command.search(name, options)
hits = pip.commands.search.transform_hits(pypi_hits)`

However when running this code i get

`AttributeError: module 'pip' has no attribute 'commands'`

Does anyone have a good solution for performing pip searches in a private pypi repository with a python script?

Thank you all in advance

EDIT:

My problem was related to badly installed python environments.

Comment: How about running it as an [external system command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/89228/calling-an-external-command-in-python)? You can get back both `stdout` and `stderr`.

Comment: well these built in functions make it much easier to parse results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me.

```
-->python2 -c "import pip; print(pip.commands); print(pip.commands.search)"
<module 'pip.commands' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/__init__.pyc'>
<module 'pip.commands.search' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/search.pyc'>

-->python3 -c "import pip; print(pip.commands); print(pip.commands.search)"
<module 'pip.commands' from '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/__init__.py'>
<module 'pip.commands.search' from '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip/commands/search.py'>
```

Comment: I believe the problem is with my global python installations. Thanks for the feedback

Answer (score 0):

There is a convenient way to execute all pip commands in the same way.

```
import pip
pip._internal.main(['search', package])
```

You can replace "search" with "install" etc.

For more info, you can read [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/installing-python-module-within-code)