# How to fix 'can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory' when installing gekko

Tags: python, gekko

I'm trying to install the gekko module in my python terminal using

```
python install -m pip gekko
```

but it is throwing an error not recognizing pip:

```
can't open file 'pip': [Errno 2] No such file or directory.
```

I'm using the terminal in Pycharm with Python 3.7

Comment: For me, I made a very silly mistake, forgot that I am using Linux, so it would be `pip3` not `pip`,

Comment: I was just a beginner when I made this post--it's amazing how much I've learned since then, but makes me feel better seeing how many people have made a similar error!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You may have just switched the order:

```
python -m pip install gekko
```

Installing from the command line with pip is okay as well:

```
pip install gekko
```

If you have multiple versions of Python (such as 2.7 and 3+), sometimes you want to specify that it is for Python 3+:

```
pip3 install gekko
```

Another way to install Gekko in Python is to install from a Python script:

```
try:
    from pip import main as pipmain
except:
    from pip._internal import main as pipmain
pipmain(['install','gekko'])
```

although this isn't the preferred option. See [Installing python module within code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/installing-python-module-within-code)

Comment: One other thing to mention for those without administrative privileges to install for all users, the ```--user``` option can be added to the pip install command for local installation such as with ```pip3 install --user gekko```.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the problem: apparently in later versions of Python (I'm using 3.7) the string for the terminal doesn't need python. I also didnt need to use the -m do declare pip a module as it isn't a module.

The string that worked:

```
pip install gekko
```

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same problem, but

**$python -m pip install gekko**

worked for me.