# How do I make a install.py to install several packages with Python?

Tags: python, package, setup.py

I am enrolled in a machine learning competition and, for some reason, the submission is not a CSV file, but rather the code in Python.
In order to make it run, they asked the participants to create another file called `install.py` to automatically install all the packages used.

I need to install multiple packages (keras, numpy, etc.).

For each package, I have to use the command `os.system`. I have no idea what it does, and this is the only information that I have.

Yes, this type of question was asked before, but not with several packages and this specific `os.system` line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if this might work for your specific issues. Give it a go.

```
import os

packages = ["keras","sklearn"] #etc

for package in packages:
    os.system("pip install "+ package) #installs particular package
```

Comment: This will work, so long as pip is in the path of the OS.

Answer (score 0):

The way I recommend doing this is to import pip as a module, as follows: (untested)

```
import pip

def install(package):
    if hasattr(pip, 'main'):
        pip.main(['install', package])
    else:
        pip._internal.main(['install', package])

packages = [] #Add your packages as strings
for package in packages:
    install(package)
```

I used [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/installing-python-module-within-code) for most of the code.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a requirements.txt file with all of your package requirements.

```
import os

os.system("pip install -r requirements.txt")
```