# How to fix the "Module not found" issue when it is already installed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, path, anaconda

I try to import BeautifulSoup but it does tell me that the module can not be found. I use Python 3.7.3 and the Atom Editor

But it is installed

```
Requirement already satisfied: BeautifulSoup in C:users\ich\anaconda\lib\site-packages (4,7,1)

Requirement already satisfied: BeautifulSoup in C:users\ich\anaconda\lib\site-packages (from BeautifulSoup4) (1.8)
```

Since I am completely new about programming I don't know how to solve it. Setting an environment variable? Or putting the .atom File into my_env ? How can I activate packages which are already installed (when import ... is not working ?)

Should I put the path C:users\ich\anaconda\lib\site-packages (4,7,1) into .atom file ?

Comment: run `py -0` in cmd

Comment: the command "py" cannot be found

Comment: `python -m pip install bs4`

Comment: so it said that it successfully built bs4. When I however try to run it in atom it still says "Module cannot be found". File C:\Program Files\.atom\Neuer Ordner\test2.py in <module> from bs4 import beautifulSoup - No module named `bs4`

Comment: do u have both anaconda & python; reopen Atom Editor

Comment: and I get the same of above "Requirement already satisfied" and so on. So I suggest I have Problems with my Path - I just dont know how to configure it properly

Comment: Yes I have both. I reopened Atom, unfortunately that didn't help

Comment: Anaconda version

Comment: Builcd Channel py37_0 ; Version 2019.03

Comment: `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup`

Comment: in script; bs4  is the package name

Comment: i tried with ´´´from bs4 import BeautifulSoup´´´ but it does not work.

Comment: in Atom which flavor you use

Comment: atom 1.37.0 Electron 2.0.18

Comment: in Atom which u use -  anaconda or python

Comment: Oh I thought it would be python but the path is actually  ```C:Users\Ich\Anaconda3\pkgs\conda-4.6.14-py37_0\Scripts```

Comment: run with python pip ; `import sys;print(sys.executable)`

Comment: hm "import cannot be found"

Comment: that should be run in script; 
Try this [Installing python module within code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50255019)

Comment: `sys.path` value

Comment: Try this [customized sublime text](https://github.com/SmartManoj/CST3)

Answer (score 0):

You must make sure that the Python interpreter runs from your conda environment.
On the command line, you'd achieve that with:

```
conda activate base
python
```

I hope somebody else can share how to do that with the Atom editor.

Comment: ```"I hope somebody else can share how to do that with the Atom editor"```                  I will definitely hand out my last slice of pizza for the people who do this