# Import runtime installed module using pip in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, subprocess

I want to install and import `Python 3` modules at runtime.

I'm using the following function to install modules at runtime using `pip`:

```
def installModules(modules):
    for module in modules:
        print("Installing module {}...".format(module))

        subprocess.call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", "--user", module])
```

The module is installed successfully, but I'm not able to import it at runtime, after the installation finishes. So if I do:

```
modules = [ "wget", "zipfile2" ]
installModules(module)
import wget
```

I get a `ModuleNotFoundError`. If, after that, I start another Python 3 session, I am able to use the modules e.g. `wget`, which means that the modules have been installed, but they are not available for this current Python 3 session.

Is it possible in Python 3 to install and then import the installed modules in the same Python 3 session i.e. right after installation?

Thank you!

**EDIT:**

On a fresh Ubuntu 19.04 install inside VirtualBox, after a `sudo apt-get install python3-pip`, running the following script:

```
import os, sys
import subprocess


def installModules(modules):
    for module in modules:
        print("Installing module {}...".format(module))

        subprocess.call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", "--user", module])

def process():
    modulesToInstall = [ "wget", "zipfile2" ]
    installModules(modulesToInstall)

process()

import wget

def main():
    wget.download("http://192.168.2.234/test/configure.py")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I get:

```
user@user-VirtualBox:~$ python3 script.py
Installing module wget...
Collecting wget
Installing collected packages: wget
Successfully installed wget-3.2
Installing module zipfile2...
Collecting zipfile2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/60/ad/d6bc08f235b66c11bbb76df41b973ce93544a907cc0e23c726ea374eee79/zipfile2-0.0.12-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Installing collected packages: zipfile2
Successfully installed zipfile2-0.0.12
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "script.py", line 17, in <module>
    import wget
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wget'
```

The Python 3 version is:

```
user@user-VirtualBox:~$ python3 --version
Python 3.7.3
```

The `pip3` version is:

```
user@user-VirtualBox:~$ pip3 --version
pip 18.1 from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip (python 3.7)
```

Other info:

```
user@user-VirtualBox:~$ whereis python3
python3: /usr/bin/python3.7m /usr/bin/python3.7-config /usr/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/python3.7m-config /usr/lib/python3.7 /usr/lib/python3.8 /usr/lib/python3 /etc/python3.7 /etc/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.7 /usr/include/python3.7m /usr/include/python3.7 /usr/share/python3 /usr/share/man/man1/python3.1.gz
```

Any ideas?

Comment: @JohnHennig Thank you for your time, please see my edits

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By default, at startup *Python* adds the *user site-packages* *dir* (I'm going to refer to it as *USPD*) in the module search paths. But this **only happens if the directory exists on the file system (disk)**. I didn't find any official documentation to support this statement <sup>***1***</sup>, so I spent some time debugging and wondering why things seem to be so weird.

The above behavior has a major impact on this particular scenario (`pip install --user`). Considering the state (at startup) of the *Python* process that will install modules:

1. *USPD* exists:

   - Things are straightforward, everything works *OK*
2. *USPD* doesn't exist:

   - Module installation will create it
   - But, since it's not in the module search paths, all the modules installed there won't be available for (simple) *import* statements

When another *Python* process is started, it will fall under ***#1.***

To fix things, *USPD* should be manually added to module search paths. Here's how the (beginning of the) script should look like:

```py
import os
import site
import subprocess
import sys

user_site = site.getusersitepackages()
if user_site not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(user_site)

# ...
```

---

#### Update *#0*

<sup>***1***</sup>  I just came across [[Python]: PEP 370 - Per user site-packages directory - Implementation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0370/#implementation) (**emphasis** is mine):

> The site module gets a new method *adduserpackage()* which adds the appropriate directory to the search path. **The directory is not added if it doesn't exist when Python is started**.