# Is it possible to download tensorflow library and use without installation?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have to use tensorflow on a server where I don't have access to `pip install` or anything like that.

I know for custom python modules you want to import you can usually just do

```py
import sys
sys.path.append('path/to/module')
import module
```

Is there a way I can just download tensorflow library and import it like this?

Answer (score 0):

I often find myself in similar situations when I have to run Python scripts that use 3rd party modules in servers where I do not have access to a cmd.

One solution is to install the package within the Python script, using the following function (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15950647/7144368)):

You can also use something like:

```
import pip

def install(package):
    if hasattr(pip, 'main'):
        pip.main(['install', package])
    else:
        pip._internal.main(['install', package])
```

This way you can install Tensorflow running `install('tensorflow)`.

Comment: Thank you for your response. The problem with this answer is that installing the package won't help me, since all I can do is reference files on the server, not packages installed on the server machine.