# installation of numpy inside the shell using conda

Tags: python, installation, conda, freecad

For some reason I get the error message:

> During initialization the error Something is wrong with the numpy installation. While importing we detected an older version of numpy in ['C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\bin\lib\site-packages\numpy']. One method of fixing this is to repeatedly uninstall numpy until none is found, then reinstall this version. occurred in C:\Users\foobar\AppData\Roaming\FreeCAD\Mod\A2plus\InitGui.py
>   Please look into the log file for further information

whenever I run FreeCAD on a specific computer. Now I could use any of [these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/installing-python-module-within-code) to install packages using pip inside Python console (Python REPL shell), except the new FreeCAD uses conda. [This post](https://forum.freecadweb.org/viewtopic.php?t=20674#p160500) suggests installing numpy by downloading and unarchiving the zip file which I think is a bad idea. My environment is:

- OS: Windows 10
- Word size of OS: 64-bit
- Word size of FreeCAD: 64-bit
- Version: 0.18.16131 (Git)
- Build type: Release
- Branch: releases/FreeCAD-0-18
- Hash: 3129ae4296e40ed20e7b3d460b86e6969acbe1c3
- Python version: 3.6.6
- Qt version: 5.6.2
- Coin version: 4.0.0a
- OCC version: 7.3.0
- Locale: English/UnitedStates (en_US)

I would appreciate it if you could help me know what is the problem and how I can solve it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "new FreeCAD uses conda" is the "new" version the "FreeCAD 0.18" one or is that the old version. Anyway, try using `pip uninstall numpy` before `conda install numpy`

Comment: @FlyingTeller I'm not sure since when FreeCAd uses conda instead of pip, so I can't comment on that. sure I would do `pip ...` or `conda ...` if there was a way to communicate with embedded pip/conda inside FreeCAD.

Comment: Is there a `C:\Program Files\FreeCAD 0.18\bin\python.exe?`

Comment: @FlyingTeller yes there is. can I run `python -m pip ...` or `python -m conda ...` inside that folder with that executable?

Comment: probably not `python -m conda`, but you could try `python -m pip uninstall numpy` and then try installing `numpy` again

Comment: @FlyingTeller but how can I install numpy after uninstalling?

Comment: What did you try when you created the error message that is in your question?

Comment: I searched the internet for a similar error message, posted a bug report on the A2plus repository, uninstalled and reinstalled FreeCAD.