# pkg_resources.get_distribution("mymodule").version not updated after reload

Tags: python, pip, packaging

I'm checking if a package is out of date using

```
pkg_resources.get_distribution("mymodule").version
```

If the version isn't matching the latest, I'm running `pip install --upgrade git+...`. Doing `reload('mymodule')` is correctly representing the changes, but the above-mentioned snippet still shows the previous version even though the version was bumped in `setup.py`

I guess the version is only updated per python session? Any other ways of getting live information? Would it be safe to read the latest `dist-info` directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would give `reload(pkg_resources)` a try:

```
>>> import pkg_resources
>>> pkg_resources.get_distribution('thing').version
'0.0.0.dev1'
>>> # in a different shell session install the new version of thing
... 
>>> pkg_resources.get_distribution('thing').version
'0.0.0.dev1'
>>> import importlib
>>> importlib.reload(pkg_resources)
<module 'pkg_resources' from '/tmp/tmp.VEueUV76hD/Thing/.tox/develop/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py'>
>>> pkg_resources.get_distribution('thing').version
'0.0.0.dev2'
```

See https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/373

Comment: Indeed, `reload` seems to do the trick! Thanks for the detailed answer.