# How to move Python virtualenv to different system (computer) and use packages present in Site-packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, operating-system, virtualenv, site-packages

I am making a python 3 application (flask based) and for that I created a virtualenv in my development system, installed all packages via pip and my app worked fine.

But when I moved that virtualenv to a different system (python3 installed) and ran my application with the absolute path of my virtualenv python **(c:/......./myenv/Scripts/python.exe main.py)** then it threw the errors that packages are not installed,
I activated the virtualenv and used pip freeze and there were no packages were installed.

*But under virtualenv there is 'Site-Packages' (myenv -> lib -> site-packages) , all my installed packages were persent there.*

**My Question is how to use the packages that are inside 'site-packages' even after moving the virtualenv to different system in Python 3.**

Comment: You don't move or copy virtual environments, you should create a new one from your `requirements.txt`.

Comment: How to install packages in virtualenv without activating virtualenv ? And packages are present in site-packages how to uses that?

Comment: Well, how did you create the original virtual environment?

Comment: by using this 'Virtualenv myenv '

Answer (score 4):

Moving a virtualenv from a computer to another, and even on the same computer from a location to another is a **bad idea** , and this is why :

- Since a lot of the binaries and libs are symlinks, and linked to your old system binaries and libs, it won't work on other machines.
- Since many of `bin/` scripts in your  virtualenv depends on the virtualenv **`path`** on the **system** , it won't work if you moved the virtualenv to another location (even on same system either .)

So the recommend way is :

- First generate requirements.txt file :

  ```
   pip freeze > requirements.txt
  ```
- Second after moving everything (except the virtualenv directory) create a new virtualenv, activate it and run :

  ```
   pip install -r requirements.txt
  ```

**Finally** in your case if you really didn't generated a requirements.txt file, and need to use the old `site-packages` , there is a dirty workaround which i tried once on a gnu/linux machine and somehow worked but am **not 100% sure** if it will work properly so if you want give it a try.

- copy the `site-packages` in `your-old-virtualenv/lib/python{version}/` somewhere in your new computer , Desktop for example
- Delete the old virtualenv, and create a new virtualenv
- Replace the `site-packages` in the **new virtualenv** in `new-virtualenv/lib/python{version}` with the **old** `site-packages`
- Delete `__pycache__` folder in the newly copied `site-packages`
- Activate the new virtualenv and test if everything is working .

**Note** that you should use the same python version either 2 or 3 , don't expect a virtualenv that depends on python2 to run properly with python3

Comment: I will try this ( replacing site-packages).. but how to pip install packages to virtualenv from a python script? Because when i move my application to different systems i dont want to manually activate virtualenv and then install packages.. ( because it's a final app for a client and can't do manual install)

Comment: read here on how to install packages from within a python script  - https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#id32 , also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/installing-python-module-within-code  . and please if the work-around worked properly please mark this answer  accepted

Comment: Does replacing site-packages worked ? i tried that many time on Gnu/Linux systems but never on Windows .

Comment: sorry for the late reply.. and no replacing site packages didn't workded.. 
I made a solution that i dynamically creates new virtualenv and install packages on that

Comment: ok..Glad to hear that you managed to make a solution, i was not sure if replacing site-packages will work properly, anyway

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can consider using **pipenv** to control the virtualenvs on different computer or environment.

Answer (score 0):

You Must not copy & paste venv, even in the same system. 
If you install new package in **venv-copied**, then it would installed in **venv-original**. 
 Becaus settings are bound to specific directory.