# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dataviz'

Tags: python

i was trying to generate clusters with dataviz got error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dataviz'
>
> from dataviz import generate_clusters

i tried !pip install dataviz got info Requirement already satisfied but error still shows

Comment: are you trying in Python Shell? if yes then please exit and then again open the shell

Comment: please try to restart the session or kernel and try importing again

Comment: tried both could not help

Comment: Always use a virtualenv to install pip packages. This eliminates lot of trouble.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably a difference in python environment between your script environment, and `pip`'s environment.

To learn more about your environment, you can run:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.executable
'/usr/bin/python'
>>> sys.version
'2.7.12 (default, Oct  8 2019, 14:14:10) \n[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]'
>>> sys.path
['/usr/lib/python2.7',
 ...
]
```

from a python prompt, if you can bring one up.

I've often found that

```
python -m pip install <packagename>
```

is more reliable than

```
pip install <packagename>
```

But that only works if you're executing your script at a shell level, without some other python environment being put in front.

You could also try [Installing python module within code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/#15950647)