# NameError: name 'pip_install' is not defined

Tags: python

I want to install few packages through python, i wrote the following code

```
def install_dependencies():
        pip_install("colorama")
        pip_install("console-menu")

install_dependencies()
```

When i run this, i am getting the following error:

```
NameError: name 'pip_install' is not defined
```

What is the package name available for pip_install

Comment: You are calling the `pip_install()` function, but you have not defined that function locally nor imported it from anywhere, so of course it is an unknown function name.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing python module within code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/installing-python-module-within-code)

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing it like that? I don't even think you can install a python library by doing what you are doing. Why not use something like os.system???

```
import os

def install_dependencies():
        os.system("pip install colorama")
        os.system("pip install console-menu")

install_dependencies()
```

I'd honestly just do a requirements.txt that the user manually installs however. But goodluck