# What is the command in python REPL that is equivalent to `python -m` in OS shell?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering if there is a command that can be run in Python REPL and is equivalent to

```
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm
```

which is run in a bash shell?

Thanks.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-m - Is the yellow section what you need? https://docs.python.org/3/library/runpy.html#runpy.run_module

Comment: @Caramiriel: Seems like that's an answer, with just a bit of elaboration. Better than running subprocesses.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I'm curious why you think using `runpy` is superior to running subprocesses. Could you elaborate? How would you use it for the given use case?

Comment: @a_guest, ..."better" in that there's far less startup overhead, for one -- you're using the existing Python interpreter with its existing module cache. But there's the downside that a `__main__` will often think it can call `sys.exit()` safely, so you'd want to `fork()` to guard against that if the behavior of the specific code being called isn't known not to do that.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Unless you have complete knowledge about what a module does, I think it's safest to use a subprocess. The [pip docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program) have a section that explains why the only fully supported way of invoking `pip` from within a program is to use `subprocess`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`subprocess.run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run):

```
import subprocess
import sys

subprocess.run([sys.executable, '-m', 'spacy', 'download', 'en_core_web_sm'], check=True)
```

Comment: Thanks. My purpose is to make the installation affect the current python installation. There can be multiple python installations in an OS. For example, I am installing Python packages and other stuffs from the Python installation in R, not in the Python installation in my OS. Your way works. I now can't create a new post. I was wondering if you know how to do the same as `pip install lxml` but from within a Python REPL session?

Comment: @Tim You can use it similar via the `-m` switch: `python -m pip install xml` and then translate this to a `subprocess.run` call. There's a [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50255019/3767239) as well as a detailed explanation from the [pip docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/latest/user_guide/#using-pip-from-your-program).