# How to install python modules using python executable file on a computer without python?

Tags: python, node.js, python-3.x, pyinstaller, executable

I am creating a standalone python executable. The goal is for users to be able to use the program without having a python environment set up on their computers. However, there are some packages that are not wrapped within the executable and I need to install them separately:

```
pip install nodejs
pip install geckodriver-autoinstaller
```

I found an answer that describes how to do this by calling pip from within the python code but I was wondering how to install pip from within python code so I can use the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/installing-python-module-within-code) or if there is a more efficient way to do this.

Comment: You want to be able to run a command that uses python libraries without python?  I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to really accomplish here.  Why can't the end-user install python?

Comment: The executable I have is able to wrap all libraries except these two for which a separate installation is required. The users are not familiar with python and so its a requirement to have a standalone executable

Comment: What is the executable written in?  C++?  Have you looked for a public API for those packages that is not python-dependent?  It looks like Node.js has C++ extensions - https://nodejs.org/api/embedding.html.  No C++ API for geckodriver according to github - https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of pyinstaller https://pypi.org/project/pyinstaller/

```
pyinstaller /path/to/yourscript.py
```

This will create the executable file from your script and take care of all used modules.

Comment: That is what I'm doing but nodejs  is a dependency of Bokeh that is not imported when Bokeh is imported