# 'ImportError: No module named pygame' after installing pygame already

Tags: python, terminal, pygame, modulenotfounderror

I usually work with Unity, but today I decided to give pygame another go to improve my python skills. In MacOSX terminal, I installed `pygame` like so: `$ pip3 install pygame`, and everything works. Then I decided to test its functionality by quickly hopping into python in terminal: `$ python3`. Then imported it:

```
>>> import pygame
```

everything worked. Then, in my project, I was importing some of the standard modules I knew I would need:

```
import time
import pygame
import random
import os
```

and it said, after running, that the module `pygame` was not installed. Since I'm on Mac, python 2.7 is pre-installed and I might have installed `pygame` in the 2.7 directory, but I checked it all out and nothing seems to be wrong. Please help me install pygame! Thanks

Comment: Using `pip3` installs the module for Python3. It seems that when you launch your script you're probably using Python2.  Try `python3 <scriptname.py`. As a desperate resort, you could try [installing the module from within python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64455061/7675174), but that is not recommended.

Comment: Yes this works, and this is why I've been using the terminal to run python recently, but it would be much more convenient to run the code from sublime text, which you do by pressing `cmnd` + `B`, but this calls the error in the title. When I tried to install through IDLE, it said that it was already installed. I'll try running my code in IDLE and see if that works

Answer (score 0):

If yours is a recent version of MAC OS X try this:

```
python3 -m pip install -U pygame --user
```

Comment: I don't know why this is, but it doesn't work: `no such option: --levinrainey` (the user name is `levinrainey`, I double checked this by using `ls` in the `/Users` directory)