# Using within code and working with windows

Tags: python, pip

I need to install pip package from Python because the people who have to install the package cannot use command line (please don't ask).
I used answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/installing-python-module-within-code) and it did not work. In fact this installation requires stdout and stderr to be connected to something so I get an error number 2.

Comment: Could you write a bash file to just run all the pip install commands on the computer instead of having them run them directly from the command line themselves?

Comment: No because it is for people under Windows and I do not know where Python is installed. I could use the default installation directory (something like %USERPROFILE%/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python39) but they could have an older python installation. And the problem is that python is sometimes not in PATH. I found the answer below more generic.

Answer (score 0):

Running through the subprocess doc, I found the correct answer :

```
import subprocess,sys
subprocess.run([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', package],stderr=subprocess.STDOUT,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,check=True)
```

Moreover, as a bonus, what was print on stdout and stderr is displayed.