# Extending with plugins remotely -at least from a frontend

Tags: django, django-views, digital-ocean, remote-access

Hi guys I have a question just one, but it houses a series of smaller questions for clarity.

So I'm building a django app that creates virtual organizations, I'm planning on hosting with digitalocean for reasons. My app just creates a droplet and host a site ( already done that)

Now I want my users ( mainly people with zero coding knowledge or ability) to be able to install plugins to their django site using the frontend.

How do I get this working without users tampering with the settings.py file

- is it possible?
- what packages would I need?
- how would I setup the installation process?

> an example would be how shopify handles its plugins and installation from the frontend remotely - if shopify were built on django.

Cheers!

Comment: I'm sure it's possible. You may want to look at this SO thread: [pip - Installing python module within code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/installing-python-module-within-code). Once you do that, you'll need more code that opens their `settings.py` and inserts the package into `INSTALLED_APPS` (and also adds any other configuration options). Finally, you'll probably need to execute a command to restart their droplet (or restart whatever process DigitalOcean uses to serve web content).

Comment: Thanks I'll try it out, I thought of using a callback to compile the installed apps.