# how do I programmatically find details of an installed package(pip show equivalent)?

Tags: python, pip

I know there is a command `pip show` for the purpose but I would like to know whether it is possible I can fetch details by doing `import pip`? When you run `pip show` it gives info like:

```
pip show requests
Name: requests
Version: 2.26.0
Summary: Python HTTP for Humans.
Home-page: https://requests.readthedocs.io
Author: Kenneth Reitz
Author-email: me@kennethreitz.org
License: Apache 2.0
Location: /anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages
Requires: urllib3, certifi, charset-normalizer, idna
Required-by: yarg, wordpress-api, WooCommerce, web3, vvm, tweepy, tika, stellar-sdk, stellar-base-sseclient, Sphinx, spacy, smart-open, requests-toolbelt, requests-oauthlib, requests-html, python3-nmap, python-binance, pyArango, poetry, pigar, pandas-datareader, MechanicalSoup, mara-pipelines, kubernetes, ipfshttpclient, hdfs, google-cloud-storage, google-api-core, discum, conda, conda-build, ccxt, CacheControl, browsermob-proxy, bravado, apache-beam, anaconda-project, anaconda-client, alpha-vantage, facebook-sdk
```

I need data in `Required-by` field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Playing with [pip source code](https://github.com/pypa/pip), I found the following solution
which works for Python 3.8.1 and pip 21.0.1 .

```
from pip._internal.commands.show import search_packages_info as search_packages_info
    
package_name='requests'

# here I use next, because search_packages_info returns a generator
package_info=next(search_packages_info([package_name]))
required_by=package_info['required_by']
```

**Example output (it is dependent on the used python environment)**

```
['requests-unixsocket', 'pysolr', 'jupyterlab-server']
```

Comment: Nice. Appreciate your effort. :)

Answer (score 0):

```py
import pip

def show(package):
    if hasattr(pip, 'main'):
        pip.main(['show', package])
    else:
        pip._internal.main(['show', package])

show('requests')
```

Or better to use current runtime:

```py
import subprocess
import sys

def show(package):
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "show", package])
    
    
show('requests')
```

Answer is inspired (overworked) by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/installing-python-module-within-code)