# Pip Install a List of Packages

Tags: python, pip

Relatively simple question, how does one pip install several packages/modules within a python script? I have a script that calls on other scripts, and several people use the main script. So when someone runs it, it needs to install or update all listed packages automatically.

I tried using the solution [linked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/installing-python-module-within-code) but was unable to get something working.

Below code,

```
# Implement pip as a subprocess:
package = ['os', 'time', 'glob2', 'selenium', 'chromedriver_binary',
           'time', 'datetime']
def install(package):
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install', package])
```

Comment: It doesn't. See above, might still be an error on my side.

Comment: `os`, `time`, and `datetime` are all python builtins

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be getting an error here, because the list items in the call to `check_call` should be strings, but you're passing `packages`, which is a *list* of strings. I think you want:

```
subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, '-m', 'pip', 'install'] + package)
```

Here, we're appending the `package` list to the arguments, so we'll end up with a command line like:

```
python -m pip install glob2 selenium...
```

Comment: I get this error,
CalledProcessError: Command '['C:\\Users\\GAS02224\\Anaconda3\\python.exe', '-m', 'pip', 'install', 'os', 'time', 'glob2', 'selenium', 'chromedriver_binary', 'time', 'datetime']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Comment: You can't `pip install` a Python builtin like `os` or `time`.