# client side how to use python script, installing package

Tags: python, module, pip, package, pywin32

I added some code snippets to python script and sent him to client. There is new library, does the the other side to install also package? `pip install pywin32`

code that added by me to script is;

```
import win32com.client
xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")  #instantiate excel app

wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(r'C:\Users\jay\Desktop\PythonInOffice\python_run_macro\macro.xlsm')
xl.Application.Run('macro.xlsm!Module1.macro1("Jay")')
wb.Save()
xl.Application.Quit()
```

From answers':
if I write the code below do I need to install sys and subprocess separetely also?

```
import subprocess
import sys

def install('pywin32'):
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", 'pywin32'])
```

Comment: yes, that's mostly the case, unless he already had it installed for some reason ...

Comment: are not there any way to install it before script runs for client?

Comment: you can obviously run pip install in a subprocess using python if it doesn't exist on system to install it.

Comment: would be great if you could share a code snippet about it

Comment: [this answer should answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/installing-python-module-within-code), you just have to catch the `module not found error`.

Comment: subprocess and sys are python built-in modules, python comes with them, you don't need to install them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope below code helps

Normally check for if package there if not installs it

```
import sys
import subprocess
import pkg_resources

required = {'pywin32'}
installed = {pkg.key for pkg in pkg_resources.working_set}
missing = required - installed

if missing:
    python = sys.executable
    subprocess.check_call([python, '-m', 'pip', 'install', *missing], stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
```

NOTE:- if proxy being used, it won't work. on check_call enter proxy details to install

Comment: if you could describe more in detail every step that would be useful much.

Comment: I edited the code, could you look up please due @Ahmed AEK

Comment: @Ahmed AEK, I trie your code with `tkinter` it gave me an error `ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tkinter (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tkinter`