# How do I download pydub from PyCharm 2022.1.3?

Tags: python, pydub, python-2.1

This is my first time asking a question in Stack Overflow. I was trying to convert from wav to mp3 but when I wanted to download pydub it shows a syntax error. What should I do in this situation?

```
pip download pydub
from pydub import AudioSegment
AudioSegment.converter = "REDACTED.wav"

wav = AudioSegment.from_wav(Path)
wav.export(r"REDACTED.mp3",format="mp3")
```

pip download pydub
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

I expect to make sure that pydub can work after the download and hoping to convert the rest wav files to mp3 automatically without any websites.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I Install a Python module within code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/how-can-i-install-a-python-module-within-code)

Comment: I tried to code this way, but it did not work.

Comment: "it did not work" isn't reall helpful. What exactly did not work.

Comment: python 2.1 really ?

Comment: @Vulpex I put a code from a user, Aaron de Windt, but still didn't work. Here is a code:import subprocess
import sys

def install(package):
    subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", package])
pip install pydub
from pydub import AudioSegment
AudioSegment.converter = "C://Users//user//Desktop//Портфолио Ариши//Программирование//Chuck//Музыка/First own sound effect.wav"

wav = AudioSegment.from_wav(Path)
wav.export(r"First own sound effect.mp3",format="mp3")

Comment: The code you've shown is non functional.

Comment: @Vulpex How do I exactly fix a bug from non-functional into a functional?

Comment: Can you further elaborate on what exactly you're trying to do? It seems you want to install a python package via pip through your python script, am I assuming this correctly? Or do you just want to generally install the package once on your own system and then run the script?

Comment: @Vulpex I would like to generally install the package once on your own system and then run the script, so then I can convert a file from wav to mp3.

Answer (score 0):

Oh I see now. you are trying to download pip download pydub. Instead execute the code in the terminal as:

pip install pydub

if you are using colab:
!pip install pydub

Comment: What I mean is that: execute the pip command in the terminal

Answer (score 0):

So after getting the confusion cleared up in the comments.

I'm assuming you're running on Windows in this scenario, what you want to do:
Open a Terminal and write the command `python -m pip install pydub`
This will install the package to the default enviornment. After that you can import the package in your python script and run it with your code above.

What you've tried above, at least I assume, is to run the pip install command from within your script, for that to work you'll have to open a subprocess and pass the command I've shown above with the code from the possible duplicate link I've commented.