# How to install Pip through a python terminal before running a program

Tags: python, pip

Im trying to find a way to install pip through a python terminal with running in the same script as my python code, something like...

install pip

pip install Module

The code I want to run

I've tried other resources but I can't run a python terminal but can run the coding aspect.

Comment: You'll have to give us more details about the kind of terminal you're in. Usually you'd be in some kind of shell where you can run `python`, but you could be in a notebook of some kind. You could also be at the Python interactive prompt, but I'm not sure why you'd want to run pip there instead of at the shell prompt before running Python.

Comment: It's not totally clear to me what you're asking, but maybe this post can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12332975/how-can-i-install-a-python-module-within-code

Answer (score 1):

From command line you can run:

```
[...]$ python -m ensurepip --upgrade
```

From python prompt/code:

```
import ensurepip

ensurepip.bootstrap(upgrade=True)
```

- [Pip installation from pip website](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/)
- [Pip installation from python website](https://docs.python.org/3/installing/index.html#pip-not-installed)