# PIP module has no attribute "main"

Tags: python

EDIT: The computer in question was a client machine with restrictions on what software could be installed. I'm unsure if that may have been a cause of the issue or if the client's IT department gave the machine a corrupted version of pip. The recommended answers below probably would have worked but were blocked by the company's IT department and required admin login to do. I have since left that project and hope to avoid similar situations.

I'm attempting to install a WHL file

While attempting to run:

```
import pip
my_path = <a path to the WHL file>
pip.main(['install', my_path])
```

I received an Attribute error:

```
'module' object has no attribute 'main'
```

I ran help(pip) and

```
__main__
```

was listed as a package content.

I'm running Python 3.4 in the console.

Comment: `'main' != '__main__'`

Comment: What version of pip do you have? May be worthwhile to run `pip install --upgrade pip` to make sure you have the most recent version.

Comment: @ChristopherApple When running `pip install` in Powershell I received: `ImportError: cannot import name 'main'`

Comment: Seems like there is some problem with your pip install. Maybe try `easy_install pip` or `easy_install --upgrade pip`

Answer (score 27):

they made a refactoring. you can support both 9 and 10 pip by using:

```
try:
    from pip import main as pipmain
except:
    from pip._internal.main import main as pipmain
```

and then use pipmain as you used pip.main. for example

```
pipmain(['install', "--upgrade", "pip"])
pipmain(['install', "-q", "package"])
```

Comment: Any ideas on "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable" with this solution?

Comment: it seems pip has updated the code structure. I edited my comment:
from pip._internal.main import main as pipmain

Answer (score 11):

`easy_install --upgrade pip` worked for me.

Answer (score 9):

My issue was related to my IDE (PyCharm). older versions of PyCharm does not support pip v10. Upgrading PyCharm solved it for me.

Comment: Can you please specify which version of PyCharm you did use to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

For more recent versions of pip (pip>=10.0.0), the functionality described in the other answers will no longer work. I recommend running the `pip` with [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) as follows:

```
import subprocess
import sys

my_path = <a path to the WHL file>
command_list = [sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", my_path]
with subprocess.Popen(command_list, stdout=subprocess.PIPE) as proc:
    print(proc.stdout.read())
```

This solution uses the current python executable to run the pip command as a commandline command. It was inspired by the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50255019/6804636).

Answer (score 1):

From pip 20.0.0, it's:

```py
from pip._internal.cli.main import main as pipmain
```