How to pip install from a text file skipping unreachable libraries
I'm currently in a scenario where I need to install the following:
pip install -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/intro-stat-learning/ISLP_labs/v2.1.3/requirements.txt

What happens is that the library scipy is not available for some reason, resulting in the following error:
(test_islp) PS C:\Users\project> pip install -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/intro-stat-learning/ISLP_labs/v2.1.3/requirements.txt 
Collecting numpy==1.24.2 (from -r https://raw.githubusercontent.com/intro-stat-learning/ISLP_labs/v2.1.3/requirements.txt (line 1))
...
...
ERROR: No matching distribution found for scipy==1.11.1

Is there a way to simply ignore libraries that return such error, and still go on with the installation of the remaining libraries?
I tried using --ignore-installed but it still leads to the same error
The quick and dirty solution would be to simply copy and paste the requirements into a text file, delete scipy and perform pip install again. That is not ideal for me because in a scenario with hundreds of libraries and dozens of potential missing distributions it could lead to tedious work.

Note that the requirements file should be consistent. Since installation from it fails, that suggests the requirements file is inconsistent for your particular version of Python; either due to the Python version, or due to the underlying OS. For example, Python 3.8 is compatible with NumPy 1.24.2, but not with 1.11.1

@9769953 sorry that was a typo(spacy vs scipy), my bad

Shell script to run pip install one by one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21311174/7976758

It's unclear in which scenario it would be useful to install only a subset of the required dependencies. The fact that pip aborts is a feature, not a bug.

@tripleee In my case I cannot edit the URL in which the requirements are stored, which stops me from proceed further with the installation

Just curl it and edit the downloaded file, then?

For sure that might work! :) But in the 'What I don't want' section I explain why this may not be optimal, because it force me to do it manually, which increases the probabilities of mistakes

You can use this simple python script to loop through all the packages in the requirements.txt and install them.  As far as I can tell, this works on Linux and Windows, not sure about Mac.
import subprocess

def install_packages(requirements_file):
    with open(requirements_file, 'r') as file:
        packages = file.readlines()

    for package in packages:
        package = package.strip()
        try:
            subprocess.check_call(['pip', 'install', package])
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
            print(f"Error installing package: {package}")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    requirements_file = 'requirements.txt'
    install_packages(requirements_file)


@9769953 Yes, what this little script does it just try and install everything, but doesn't end on fail, as this is what I though Nauel needed.

It seems to install scipy == 1.11.1 fine, as a distribution was found for it

@9769953 If you were to try a distribution that doesn't exist, like scipy==1.76.35, then the script will correctly continue and skip it.

Isn't there a build in command to use directly on the CLI?

@Nauel There might be, but I do not know it.  However, this small script should work fine.  Just run it in the command line or make a file and run it with python filename.py

@Nauel "Isn't there a build in command to use directly on the CLI?" No, there isn't.

This simply assumes your requirements.txt does not contain comments or other decorations like platform-specific constraints.

@tripleee It will try to download whatever your comment it, which will likely fail and just skip it
